# Renaming column names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe, rename

I want to change the column labels of a Pandas DataFrame from

```
['$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e']
```

to

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 2540, accepted):

Just assign it to the `.columns` attribute:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [10,20]})
>>> df
   $a  $b
0   1  10
1   2  20

>>> df.columns = ['a', 'b']
>>> df
   a   b
0  1  10
1  2  20
```

Answer (score 4540):

### Rename Specific Columns

Use the [`df.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) function and refer the columns to be renamed. Not all the columns have to be renamed:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'})

# Or rename the existing DataFrame (rather than creating a copy) 
df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'}, inplace=True)
```

**Minimal Code Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame('x', index=range(3), columns=list('abcde'))
df

   a  b  c  d  e
0  x  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  x  x  x
```

The following methods all work and produce the same output:

```
df2 = df.rename({'a': 'X', 'b': 'Y'}, axis=1)
df2 = df.rename({'a': 'X', 'b': 'Y'}, axis='columns')
df2 = df.rename(columns={'a': 'X', 'b': 'Y'}) 

df2

   X  Y  c  d  e
0  x  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  x  x  x
```

Remember to assign the result back, as the modification is not-inplace. Alternatively, specify `inplace=True`:

```
df.rename({'a': 'X', 'b': 'Y'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df

   X  Y  c  d  e
0  x  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  x  x  x
```

You can specify `errors='raise'` to raise errors if an invalid column-to-rename is specified.

---

### Reassign Column Headers

Use [`df.set_axis()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) with `axis=1`.

```
df2 = df.set_axis(['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], axis=1)
df2

   V  W  X  Y  Z
0  x  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  x  x  x
```

Headers can be assigned directly:

```
df.columns = ['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
df

   V  W  X  Y  Z
0  x  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  x  x  x
```

Answer (score 517):

The [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method can take a ***function***, for example:

```
In [11]: df.columns
Out[11]: Index([u'$a', u'$b', u'$c', u'$d', u'$e'], dtype=object)

In [12]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: x[1:], inplace=True)

In [13]: df.columns
Out[13]: Index([u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 274):

As documented in *[Working with text data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html)*:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('$', '')
```

Answer (score 202):

## Pandas 0.21+ Answer

There have been some significant updates to column renaming in version 0.21.

- The [`rename` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/whatsnew.html#rename-reindex-now-also-accept-axis-keyword) has added the `axis` parameter which may be set to `columns` or `1`. This update makes this method match the rest of the pandas API. It still has the `index` and `columns` parameters but you are no longer forced to use them.
- The [`set_axis` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_axis) with the `inplace` set to `False` enables you to rename all the index or column labels with a list.

### Examples for Pandas 0.21+

Construct sample DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [3,4], 
                   '$c':[5,6], '$d':[7,8], 
                   '$e':[9,10]})

   $a  $b  $c  $d  $e
0   1   3   5   7   9
1   2   4   6   8  10
```

#### Using `rename` with `axis='columns'` or `axis=1`

```
df.rename({'$a':'a', '$b':'b', '$c':'c', '$d':'d', '$e':'e'}, axis='columns')
```

or

```
df.rename({'$a':'a', '$b':'b', '$c':'c', '$d':'d', '$e':'e'}, axis=1)
```

Both result in the following:

```
   a  b  c  d   e
0  1  3  5  7   9
1  2  4  6  8  10
```

It is still possible to use the old method signature:

```
df.rename(columns={'$a':'a', '$b':'b', '$c':'c', '$d':'d', '$e':'e'})
```

The `rename` function also accepts functions that will be applied to each column name.

```
df.rename(lambda x: x[1:], axis='columns')
```

or

```
df.rename(lambda x: x[1:], axis=1)
```

---

#### Using `set_axis` with a list and `inplace=False`

You can supply a list to the `set_axis` method that is equal in length to the number of columns (or index). Currently, `inplace` defaults to `True`, but `inplace` will be defaulted to `False` in future releases.

```
df.set_axis(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], axis='columns', inplace=False)
```

or

```
df.set_axis(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

---

#### Why not use `df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`?

There is nothing wrong with assigning columns directly like this. It is a perfectly good solution.

The advantage of using `set_axis` is that it can be used as part of a method chain and that it returns a new copy of the DataFrame. Without it, you would have to store your intermediate steps of the chain to another variable before reassigning the columns.

```
# new for pandas 0.21+
df.some_method1()
  .some_method2()
  .set_axis()
  .some_method3()

# old way
df1 = df.some_method1()
        .some_method2()
df1.columns = columns
df1.some_method3()
```

Answer (score 160):

Since you only want to remove the $ sign in all column names, you could just do:

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('$', ''))
```

OR

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('$', ''), inplace=True)
```

Comment: This one not only helps in OP's case but also in generic requirements. 
E.g.: to split a column name by a separator and use one part of it.

Answer (score 141):

Renaming columns in Pandas is an easy task.

```
df.rename(columns={'$a': 'a', '$b': 'b', '$c': 'c', '$d': 'd', '$e': 'e'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I will up this since It is naturally supported.

Comment: much better than approved solution

Comment: The `columns` arg here can also be a function. So if you want to remove the first char from each name you can do `df.rename(columns=lambda name: name[1:], inplace=True)` ([ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#basics-rename))

Comment: It's very natural. You can do it for arbitrary columns. It should be an accepted answer.

Comment: also give a label to an unlabelled column using this method: df.rename(columns={0: "x", 1: "y", 2: "z"})

Answer (score 82):

Use:

```
old_names = ['$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e'] 
new_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_names, new_names)), inplace=True)
```

This way you can manually edit the `new_names` as you wish. It works great when you need to rename only a few columns to correct misspellings, accents, remove special characters, etc.

Comment: I like this approach, but I think `df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` is simpler.

Comment: I like this method of zipping old and new names. We can use `df.columns.values` to get the old names.

Comment: I display the tabular view and copy the columns to old_names.
I copy the requirement array to new_names.
Then use dict(zip(old_names, new_names))
Very elegant solution.

Comment: I often use subsets of lists from something like:  `myList = list(df)  myList[10:20]` , etc - so this is perfect.

Comment: Best to take the old names as @bkowshik suggested, then edit them and re-insert them, ie `namez = df.columns.values` followed by some edits, then `df.columns = namez`.

Answer (score 44):

## One line or Pipeline solutions

I'll focus on two things:

1. OP clearly states

   > I have the edited column names stored it in a list, but I don't know how to replace the column names.

   I do not want to solve the problem of how to replace `'$'` or strip the first character off of each column header.  OP has already done this step.  Instead I want to focus on replacing the existing `columns` object with a new one given a list of replacement column names.
2. `df.columns = new` where `new` is the list of new columns names is as simple as it gets.  The drawback of this approach is that it requires editing the existing dataframe's `columns` attribute and it isn't done inline.  I'll show a few ways to perform this via pipelining without editing the existing dataframe.

---

**Setup 1**
To focus on the need to rename of replace column names with a pre-existing list, I'll create a new sample dataframe `df` with initial column names and unrelated new column names.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Jack': [1, 2], 'Mahesh': [3, 4], 'Xin': [5, 6]})
new = ['x098', 'y765', 'z432']

df

   Jack  Mahesh  Xin
0     1       3    5
1     2       4    6
```

---

**Solution 1**
[**`pd.DataFrame.rename`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

It has been said already that **if** you had a dictionary mapping the old column names to new column names, you could use `pd.DataFrame.rename`.

```
d = {'Jack': 'x098', 'Mahesh': 'y765', 'Xin': 'z432'}
df.rename(columns=d)

   x098  y765  z432
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

However, you can easily create that dictionary and include it in the call to `rename`.  The following takes advantage of the fact that when iterating over `df`, we iterate over each column name.

```
# Given just a list of new column names
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df, new)))

   x098  y765  z432
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

This works great if your original column names are unique.  But if they are not, then this breaks down.

---

**Setup 2**
Non-unique columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]],
    columns=['Mahesh', 'Mahesh', 'Xin']
)
new = ['x098', 'y765', 'z432']

df

   Mahesh  Mahesh  Xin
0       1       3    5
1       2       4    6
```

---

**Solution 2**
[**`pd.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) using the `keys` argument

First, notice what happens when we attempt to use solution 1:

```
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df, new)))

   y765  y765  z432
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

We didn't map the `new` list as the column names.  We ended up repeating `y765`.  Instead, we can use the `keys` argument of the `pd.concat` function while iterating through the columns of `df`.

```
pd.concat([c for _, c in df.items()], axis=1, keys=new) 

   x098  y765  z432
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

---

**Solution 3**
Reconstruct.  This should only be used if you have a single `dtype` for all columns.  Otherwise, you'll end up with `dtype` `object` for all columns and converting them back requires more dictionary work.

*Single `dtype`*

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values, df.index, new)

   x098  y765  z432
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

*Mixed `dtype`*

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values, df.index, new).astype(dict(zip(new, df.dtypes)))

   x098  y765  z432
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

---

**Solution 4**
This is a gimmicky trick with `transpose` and `set_index`.  [**`pd.DataFrame.set_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) allows us to set an index inline, but there is no corresponding `set_columns`.  So we can transpose, then `set_index`, and transpose back.  However, the same single `dtype` versus mixed `dtype` caveat from solution 3 applies here.

*Single `dtype`*

```
df.T.set_index(np.asarray(new)).T

   x098  y765  z432
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

*Mixed `dtype`*

```
df.T.set_index(np.asarray(new)).T.astype(dict(zip(new, df.dtypes)))

   x098  y765  z432
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

---

**Solution 5**
Use a `lambda` in `pd.DataFrame.rename` that cycles through each element of `new`.
In this solution, we pass a lambda that takes `x` but then ignores it.  It also takes a `y` but doesn't expect it.  Instead, an iterator is given as a default value and I can then use that to cycle through one at a time without regard to what the value of `x` is.

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x, y=iter(new): next(y))

   x098  y765  z432
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

And as pointed out to me by the folks in [*sopython* chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python), if I add a `*` in between `x` and `y`, I can protect my `y` variable.  Though, in this context I don't believe it needs protecting.  It is still worth mentioning.

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x, *, y=iter(new): next(y))

   x098  y765  z432
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

Answer (score 42):

## Column names vs Names of Series

I would like to explain a bit what happens behind the scenes.

Dataframes are a set of Series.

Series in turn are an extension of a `numpy.array`.

`numpy.array`s have a property `.name`.

This is the name of the series. It is seldom that Pandas respects this attribute, but it lingers in places and can be used to hack some Pandas behaviors.

## Naming the list of columns

A lot of answers here talks about the `df.columns` attribute being a `list` when in fact it is a `Series`. This means it has a `.name` attribute.

This is what happens if you decide to fill in the name of the columns `Series`:

```
df.columns = ['column_one', 'column_two']
df.columns.names = ['name of the list of columns']
df.index.names = ['name of the index']

name of the list of columns     column_one  column_two
name of the index
0                                    4           1
1                                    5           2
2                                    6           3
```

Note that the name of the index always comes one column lower.

### Artefacts that linger

The `.name` attribute lingers on sometimes. If you set `df.columns = ['one', 'two']` then the `df.one.name` will be `'one'`.

If you set `df.one.name = 'three'` then `df.columns` will still give you `['one', 'two']`, and `df.one.name` will give you `'three'`.

#### BUT

`pd.DataFrame(df.one)` will return

```
    three
0       1
1       2
2       3
```

Because Pandas reuses the `.name` of the already defined `Series`.

## Multi-level column names

Pandas has ways of doing multi-layered column names. There is not so much magic involved, but I wanted to cover this in my answer too since I don't see anyone picking up on this here.

```
    |one            |
    |one      |two  |
0   |  4      |  1  |
1   |  5      |  2  |
2   |  6      |  3  |
```

This is easily achievable by setting columns to lists, like this:

```
df.columns = [['one', 'one'], ['one', 'two']]
```

Answer (score 42):

Many of pandas functions have an inplace parameter. When setting it True, the transformation applies directly to the dataframe that you are calling it on. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [3,4]})
df.rename(columns={'$a': 'a'}, inplace=True)
df.columns

>>> Index(['a', '$b'], dtype='object')
```

Alternatively, there are cases where you want to preserve the original dataframe. I have often seen people fall into this case if creating the dataframe is an expensive task. For example, if creating the dataframe required querying a snowflake database. In this case, just make sure the the inplace parameter is set to False.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [3,4]})
df2 = df.rename(columns={'$a': 'a'}, inplace=False)
df.columns

>>> Index(['$a', '$b'], dtype='object')

df2.columns

>>> Index(['a', '$b'], dtype='object')
```

If these types of transformations are something that you do often, you could also look into a number of different pandas GUI tools. I'm the creator of one called [Mito](https://trymito.io/soo). It’s a spreadsheet that automatically converts your edits to python code.

Answer (score 32):

Let's *understand* renaming by a small example...

1. Renaming columns using mapping:

   ```
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]}) # Creating a df with column name A and B
    df.rename({"A": "new_a", "B": "new_b"}, axis='columns', inplace =True) # Renaming column A with 'new_a' and B with 'new_b'

    Output:

       new_a  new_b
    0  1       4
    1  2       5
    2  3       6
   ```
2. Renaming index/Row_Name using mapping:

   ```
    df.rename({0: "x", 1: "y", 2: "z"}, axis='index', inplace =True) # Row name are getting replaced by 'x', 'y', and 'z'.

    Output:

           new_a  new_b
        x  1       4
        y  2       5
        z  3       6
   ```

Answer (score 26):

Let's say this is your dataframe.

[image]

You can rename the columns using two methods.

1. Using `dataframe.columns=[#list]`

   ```
   df.columns=['a','b','c','d','e']
   ```

   [image]

   The limitation of this method is that if one column has to be changed, full column list has to be passed. Also, this method is not applicable on index labels.
   For example, if you passed this:

   ```
   df.columns = ['a','b','c','d']
   ```

   This will throw an error. Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 4 elements.
2. Another method is the Pandas `rename()` method which is used to rename any index, column or row

   ```
   df = df.rename(columns={'$a':'a'})
   ```

   [image]

Similarly, you can change any rows or columns.

Answer (score 22):

If you've got the dataframe, df.columns dumps everything into a list you can manipulate and then reassign into your dataframe as the names of columns...

```
columns = df.columns
columns = [row.replace("$", "") for row in columns]
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(columns, things)), inplace=True)
df.head() # To validate the output
```

Best way? I don't know. A way - yes.

A better way of evaluating all the main techniques put forward in the answers to the question is below using cProfile to gage memory and execution time. @kadee, @kaitlyn, and @eumiro had the functions with the fastest execution times - though these functions are so fast we're comparing the rounding of 0.000 and 0.001 seconds for all the answers. Moral: my answer above likely isn't the 'best' way.

```
import pandas as pd
import cProfile, pstats, re

old_names = ['$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e']
new_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
col_dict = {'$a': 'a', '$b': 'b', '$c': 'c', '$d': 'd', '$e': 'e'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1, 2], '$b': [10, 20], '$c': ['bleep', 'blorp'], '$d': [1, 2], '$e': ['texa$', '']})

df.head()

def eumiro(df, nn):
    df.columns = nn
    # This direct renaming approach is duplicated in methodology in several other answers:
    return df

def lexual1(df):
    return df.rename(columns=col_dict)

def lexual2(df, col_dict):
    return df.rename(columns=col_dict, inplace=True)

def Panda_Master_Hayden(df):
    return df.rename(columns=lambda x: x[1:], inplace=True)

def paulo1(df):
    return df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('$', ''))

def paulo2(df):
    return df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('$', ''), inplace=True)

def migloo(df, on, nn):
    return df.rename(columns=dict(zip(on, nn)), inplace=True)

def kadee(df):
    return df.columns.str.replace('$', '')

def awo(df):
    columns = df.columns
    columns = [row.replace("$", "") for row in columns]
    return df.rename(columns=dict(zip(columns, '')), inplace=True)

def kaitlyn(df):
    df.columns = [col.strip('$') for col in df.columns]
    return df

print 'eumiro'
cProfile.run('eumiro(df, new_names)')
print 'lexual1'
cProfile.run('lexual1(df)')
print 'lexual2'
cProfile.run('lexual2(df, col_dict)')
print 'andy hayden'
cProfile.run('Panda_Master_Hayden(df)')
print 'paulo1'
cProfile.run('paulo1(df)')
print 'paulo2'
cProfile.run('paulo2(df)')
print 'migloo'
cProfile.run('migloo(df, old_names, new_names)')
print 'kadee'
cProfile.run('kadee(df)')
print 'awo'
cProfile.run('awo(df)')
print 'kaitlyn'
cProfile.run('kaitlyn(df)')
```

Answer (score 22):

If you already have a list for the new column names, you can try this:

```
new_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
new_names_map = {df.columns[i]:new_cols[i] for i in range(len(new_cols))}

df.rename(new_names_map, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 21):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'$a': [1], '$b': [1], '$c': [1], '$d': [1], '$e': [1]})
```

If your new list of columns is in the same order as the existing columns, the assignment is simple:

```
new_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
df.columns = new_cols
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  1  1  1
```

If you had a dictionary keyed on old column names to new column names, you could do the following:

```
d = {'$a': 'a', '$b': 'b', '$c': 'c', '$d': 'd', '$e': 'e'}
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda col: d[col])  # Or `.map(d.get)` as pointed out by @PiRSquared.
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  1  1  1
```

If you don't have a list or dictionary mapping, you could strip the leading `$` symbol via a list comprehension:

```
df.columns = [col[1:] if col[0] == '$' else col for col in df]
```

Comment: Instead of `lambda col: d[col]` you could pass `d.get`... so it would look like `df.columns.map(d.get)`

Answer (score 21):

```
df.rename(index=str, columns={'A':'a', 'B':'b'})
```

*[pandas.DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)*

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 20):

Another way we could replace the original column labels is by stripping the unwanted characters (here '$') from the original column labels.

This could have been done by running a *for* loop over df.columns and appending the stripped columns to df.columns.

Instead, we can do this neatly in a single statement by using list comprehension like below:

```
df.columns = [col.strip('$') for col in df.columns]
```

(`strip` method in Python strips the given character from beginning and end of the string.)

Comment: Can you explain how/why this works? That will make the answer more valuable for future readers.

Answer (score 13):

You could use [`str.slice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) for that:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.slice(1)
```

Comment: PS: This is a more verbose equivalent to `df.columns.str[1:]`... probably better to use that, it's shorter and more obvious.

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to rename using a regular expression:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b':[3,4], '$c':[5,6]})

df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('\$','',x))
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

Answer (score 11):

My method is generic wherein you can add additional delimiters by comma separating `delimiters=` variable and future-proof it.

**Working Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re


df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [3,4],'$c':[5,6], '$d': [7,8], '$e': [9,10]})

delimiters = '$'
matchPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))
df.columns = [re.split(matchPattern, i)[1] for i in df.columns ]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df
   $a  $b  $c  $d  $e
0   1   3   5   7   9
1   2   4   6   8  10

>>> df
   a  b  c  d   e
0  1  3  5  7   9
1  2  4  6  8  10
```

Answer (score 10):

Note that the approaches in previous answers do not work for a *MultiIndex*. For a *MultiIndex*, you need to do something like the following:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({('$a','$x'):[1,2], ('$b','$y'): [3,4], ('e','f'):[5,6]})
>>> df
   $a $b  e
   $x $y  f
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
>>> rename = {('$a','$x'):('a','x'), ('$b','$y'):('b','y')}
>>> df.columns = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
        rename.get(item, item) for item in df.columns.tolist()])
>>> df
   a  b  e
   x  y  f
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have to deal with loads of columns named by the providing system out of your control, I came up with the following approach that is a combination of a general approach and specific replacements in one go.

First create a dictionary from the dataframe column names using regular expressions in order to throw away certain appendixes of column names and then add specific replacements to the dictionary to name core columns as expected later in the receiving database.

This is then applied to the dataframe in one go.

```
dict = dict(zip(df.columns, df.columns.str.replace('(:S$|:C1$|:L$|:D$|\.Serial:L$)', '')))
dict['brand_timeseries:C1'] = 'BTS'
dict['respid:L'] = 'RespID'
dict['country:C1'] = 'CountryID'
dict['pim1:D'] = 'pim_actual'
df.rename(columns=dict, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to remove the '$' sign then use the below code

```
df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns.str.replace("$", ""))
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the solution already provided, you can replace all the columns while you are reading the file. We can use `names` and `header=0` to do that.

First, we create a list of the names that we like to use as our column names:

```
import pandas as pd

ufo_cols = ['city', 'color reported', 'shape reported', 'state', 'time']
ufo.columns = ufo_cols

ufo = pd.read_csv('link to the file you are using', names = ufo_cols, header = 0)
```

In this case, all the column names will be replaced with the names you have in your list.

Answer (score 8):

My one line answer is

`df.columns = df_new_cols`

It is the best one with 1/3rd the processing time.

`timeit` comparison:

*df* has seven columns. I am trying to change a few of the names.

```
%timeit df.rename(columns={old_col:new_col for (old_col,new_col) in zip(df_old_cols,df_new_cols)},inplace=True)
214 µs ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df_old_cols,df_new_cols)),inplace=True)
212 µs ± 7.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.columns = df_new_cols
72.9 µs ± 17.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 8):

**A simple and 'fun' (and pythonic?) solution:**

```
df.rename(columns={x: x.replace('$', '') for x in df.columns})
```

Where:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e'])
```

**Steps:**

Get the columns of a DataFrame as a list:

```
df.columns
```

Method for renaming in DataFrames:

```
df.rename()
```

Attribute to specify that you want to rename columns:

```
columns={}
```

In the dictionary you need to specify which columns to rename (in each key) and which new names they will get (each value)

```
{'old_col_name': 'new_col_name', ...}
```

Since your changes follow a pattern, to remove the $ character in each column, we can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{x: x.replace('$', '') for x in df.columns}
```

Comment: The correct way is `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('$', '')` or `df.columns = df.columns.str.lstrip('$')`. As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30546734/7758804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73010626/7758804)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you can use a regular expression, this solution *removes* the need of manual encoding using a regular expression:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

srch = re.compile(r"\w+")

data = pd.read_csv("CSV_FILE.csv")
cols = data.columns
new_cols = list(map(lambda v:v.group(), (list(map(srch.search, cols)))))
data.columns = new_cols
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a nifty little function I like to use to cut down on typing:

```
def rename(data, oldnames, newname):
    if type(oldnames) == str: # Input can be a string or list of strings
        oldnames = [oldnames] # When renaming multiple columns
        newname = [newname] # Make sure you pass the corresponding list of new names
    i = 0
    for name in oldnames:
        oldvar = [c for c in data.columns if name in c]
        if len(oldvar) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Sorry, couldn't find that column in the dataset")
        if len(oldvar) > 1: # Doesn't have to be an exact match
            print("Found multiple columns that matched " + str(name) + ": ")
            for c in oldvar:
                print(str(oldvar.index(c)) + ": " + str(c))
            ind = input('Please enter the index of the column you would like to rename: ')
            oldvar = oldvar[int(ind)]
        if len(oldvar) == 1:
            oldvar = oldvar[0]
        data = data.rename(columns = {oldvar : newname[i]})
        i += 1
    return data
```

Here is an example of how it works:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 4)), columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'omg', 'idk'])
# First list = existing variables
# Second list = new names for those variables
In [3]: df = rename(df, ['col', 'omg'],['first', 'ohmy'])
Found multiple columns that matched col:
0: col1
1: col2

Please enter the index of the column you would like to rename: 0

In [4]: df.columns
Out[5]: Index(['first', 'col2', 'ohmy', 'idk'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: The use case for a function like this is extremely rare. In most cases, I know what I'm looking for and what I want to rename it to, I'd just assign/modify it myself.

Comment: @cs95 I tend to work with large national or international surveys where variables will have coded variable names that begin with prefixes depending on answer options, likert scales, and branching (such as EDU_2913.443, EDU_2913.421,...). This function has been very useful for me in working with those types of sets, I understand if its not for you though :)

Answer (score 6):

I needed to rename features for XGBoost, and it didn't like any of these:

```py
import re
regex = r"[!\"#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~ ]+"
X_trn.columns = X_trn.columns.str.replace(regex, '_', regex=True)
X_tst.columns = X_tst.columns.str.replace(regex, '_', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Rename column at a specific position

One use-case not mentioned on this page is how to rename a column by index, i.e. rename a column name at a specific position. If the column names are unique, then `rename()` would work. For example, if we want to rename the second column, the following would work.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'$A': [1, 2], '$B': ['a', 'b']})
df.rename(columns={df.columns[1]: 'new'}, inplace=True)
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- second column is renamed
```

[image: result1]

However, if the column labels are non-unique (which is a common reason to rename it by index in the first place), the above would change all duplicate column names. However, `pd.DataFrame().columns` is an immutable pandas Index object that is built on a (mutable) numpy ndarray which can be accessed as a view using `.values`/`.to_numpy()`. Modifying the underlying array by index does the job.

```py
# modify the second column name
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a', 1.2], [2, 'b', 3.4]], columns=['$A', '$B', '$B'])
df.columns[1] = 'new'             # <---- TypeError
df.columns.values[1] = 'new'      # <---- OK
df.columns.to_numpy()[1] = 'new'  # <---- OK
```

To perform the same in a chained method or create a new copy of a dataframe would require changing the entire columns object and assign using `set_axis()`:

```py
# change the second column name
df = df.set_axis([*df.columns[:1], 'new', *df.columns[2:]], axis=1)
```

[image: result2]

#### `str` methods

`pd.DataFrame().columns` also defines a `.str` accessor, which enables one to call specific string methods. For the use case in the question, one could use `removeprefix()` to remove leading `'$'`s.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'$A': [1, 2], '$B': ['a', 'b']})
df.columns = df.columns.str.removeprefix('$')
```

[image: result3]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html#pandas.Series.str.lstrip) or [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html#pandas.Series.str.strip) methods with an index:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lstrip('$')
```

or

```
cols = ['$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e']
pd.Series(cols).str.lstrip('$').tolist()
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative :** Another way to change the columns labels of the dataframe using the `translate` method.

Suppose we have the following dataframe :

```
   $a  $b  $c  $d  $e
0   1   4   7  10  13
1   2   5   8  11  14
2   3   6   9  12  15
```

**Proposed code** to achieve labels changing :

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'$a': [1, 2, 3], '$b': [4, 5, 6], '$c': [7, 8, 9], '$d': [10, 11, 12], '$e': [13, 14, 15]})

# Create a translation table that maps the '$' character to the empty string
translate_table = str.maketrans('', '', '$')

# translate the column labels
df.columns = df.columns.str.translate(translate_table)

print(df)
```

**Result**

```
   a  b  c   d   e
0  1  4  7  10  13
1  2  5  8  11  14
2  3  6  9  12  15
```