# Recoding Pandas Index Objects from a Dictionary (for Non-Ordered Replacement)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am writing a function that recodes Pandas DataFrame index objects from a `recode` dictionary.

```
recodes = {'sales' : 'CurrentSales', 'cash' : 'US$' }
```

1. Is there any built in method for this?
2. What is an efficient way of doing this?

Using an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text = '''\
STK_ID RPT_Date sales cash
000568 20120930 80.093 57.488
000596 20120930 32.585 26.177
000799 20120930 14.784 8.157
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(text), delimiter = ' ', 
                 converters = {0:str})
df.set_index(['STK_ID','RPT_Date'], inplace = True)
```

[image]

What I have implemented is essentially:

```
nw_idx = ['']*len(df.columns)
for key in recodes.keys():
    for idx, colname in enumerate(df.columns):
        if colname == key:
            nw_idx[idx] = recodes[key]

df.columns = pd.Index(nw_idx)
```

[image]

Comment: I would consider yours a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas) question, but the accepted answer there is not what I would use. Still, the [higher voted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11354850/507762) there apply to your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.rename(columns={'sales' : 'CurrentSales', 'cash' : 'US$' })
```

Comment: Oh Wow - that was simple. Thanks. I was searching the api on actual index objects ``df.columns`` etc.

Comment: @sanguineturtle You can also pass this function a list of new names, or a function (like `str.lower`). And you can assign to `df.columns` directly. Index objects have a `name` field, and can get more confusing.

Comment: It would be nice if rename could produced a "report". I might write a wrapper for adding a report for converted items, and not converted items etc.