# Pandas merge on aggregated columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I create a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,13,15], "b": [4,5,6,6,6], "c": ["wish", "you","were", "here", "here"]})
```

Like so:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   4   wish
1   2   5   you
2   3   6   were
3   13  6   here
4   15  6   here
```

... and then group and aggregate by a couple columns ...

```
gb = df.groupby(['b','c']).agg({"a": lambda x: x.nunique()})
```

Yielding the following result:

```
            a
b   c   
4   wish    1
5   you     1
6   here    2
    were    1
```

Is it possible to merge `df` with the newly aggregated table `gb` such that I create a new column in df, containing the corresponding values from `gb`? Like this:

```
    a   b   c      nc
0   1   4   wish    1
1   2   5   you     1
2   3   6   were    1
3   13  6   here    2
4   15  6   here    2
```

I tried doing the simplest thing:

```
df.merge(gb, on=['b','c'])
```

But this gives the error:

```
KeyError: 'b'
```

Which makes sense because the grouped table has a Multi-index and `b` is not a column. So my question is two-fold:

1. Can I transform the multi-index of the `gb` DataFrame back into columns (so that it has the `b` and `c` column)?
2. Can I merge `df` with `gb` on the column names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you want to add some aggregated column from groupby operation back to the df you should be using [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation), this produces a Series with its index aligned with your orig df:

```
In [4]:

df['nc'] = df.groupby(['b','c'])['a'].transform(pd.Series.nunique)
df
Out[4]:
    a  b     c  nc
0   1  4  wish   1
1   2  5   you   1
2   3  6  were   1
3  13  6  here   2
4  15  6  here   2
```

There is no need to reset the index or perform an additional merge.

Comment: This is brilliant. Much more elegant than my solution.

Comment: Agreed - @aus_lacy's answer addresses the OP's question but this is an even better way to do it.

Comment: can we do that on several operations : count / sum / etc... with an automated new columns for each operation ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple way of doing this using `reset_index()`.

```
df.merge(gb.reset_index(), on=['b','c'])
```

gives you

```
   a_x  b    c    a_y
0    1  4  wish    1
1    2  5   you    1
2    3  6  were    1
3   13  6  here    2
4   15  6  here    2
```

Comment: @EdChum's method is far superior to mine.

Comment: Is it possible to place the result of the `agg` into a new column so that the merge doesn't rename columns? The advantage of using `reset_index`, I suppose, is that the number of rows in the aggregate table corresponds to the number of aggregation keys (i.e. ['b','c']), which I may want to keep for further analysis beyond the merge.

Comment: @juniper- you would have to rename the the column names that clashed in order for the merge to not add a suffix. You can store the groupby object as a variable, it's just an object that describes how the groupby should be performed there is no performance penalty with doing this

Comment: @juniper as EdChum mentioned above, you would have to rename the columns manually to remove the suffix. See here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas

Comment: Thanks to you both! I wish I could accept both of your answers since they're both very helpful, but Ed's gets the cake for the efficiency.