# how to add columns names to a DataFrame and save it to Excel

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create an Excel file that contains 2 columns [Publisher and Frequency] but only the frequency data is in my Excel file

```
doaj_2015 = pd.read_csv('doaj_20151015_1800_utf8.csv')
publishers = doaj_2015['Publisher'].value_counts()
DataFrame(publishers, columns=['Frequency'])
publishers.to_excel('publisher.xlsx', 
                 sheet_name = 'publisher frequencies', 
                 index = False)
```

Expected Results

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`publishers` is a series.  You can reset the index, assign the result to a dataframe, rename the columns, and then export to excel (specifying no index).

```
df = publishers.reset_index()
df.columns = ['Publisher', 'Frequency']
df.to_excel('publisher.xlsx', 
            sheet_name='publisher frequencies', 
            index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas) on renaming columns.

Once you do the value counts, and coerce as a frame your index becomes the item you are counting.  Reset it by:

```
publishers.reset_index()
```

and then, you should rename your columns like this:

```
publishers.columns = ['Publisher', 'Frequency']
```