# Beautifulsoup span id tags to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have the following html:

```
</tr><tr>
<td>
<span id="Grid_exdate_43">2/15/2005</span>
</td><td>Cash</td><td>
<span id="Grid_CashAmount_43">0.08</span>
</td><td>
<span id="Grid_DeclDate_43">--</span>
</td><td>
<span id="Grid_RecDate_43">2/17/2005</span>
</td><td>
<span id="Grid_PayDate_43">3/10/2005</span>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
<span id="Grid_exdate_44">11/15/2004</span>
</td><td>Cash</td><td>
<span id="Grid_CashAmount_44">3.08</span>
</td><td>
<span id="Grid_DeclDate_44">--</span>
</td><td>
<span id="Grid_RecDate_44">11/17/2004</span>
</td><td>
<span id="Grid_PayDate_44">12/2/2004</span>
</td>
</tr><tr>
```

Each section has the same 5 items, namely: `Grid_exdate`, `Grid_CashAmount`, `Grid_DeclDate`, `Grid_RecDate`, `Grid_PayDate`. Every `id` of each section has an integer following it that increments for each section. In the above example we have sections 43 and 44.

I need to be able to save each section as a row in a pandas dataframe. The dataframe would be as follows:

```
Grid_exdate   Grid_CashAmount   Grid_DeclDate   Grid_RecDate   Grid_PayDate
2/15/2005     0.08              --              2/17/2005      3/10/2005
11/15/2004    3.08              --              11/17/2004     12/2/2004
```

I'm at a loss as to how to do this.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I've managed to figure something out that should work:

```
def get_exdate(self, id):
    return id and re.compile("Grid_exdate_").search(id)

df = pd.DataFrame()
exdate_list = []
for link in soup.find_all(id=self.get_exdate):
    exdate_list.append(link.string)

df['Grid_exdate'] = exdate_list
```

So the above code gets all the `Grid_exdate_` values using a regular expression, adding all the results to a list and then adding that as a column to the dataframe.

So ill just create 5 of these, one for each field. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know (this is probably not a very efficient way to do this). Otherwise this should do the trick.

Comment: Why doesn't [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the suggested solutions. In the end I went with the following which seems to have been the least complicated solution:

```
def get_exdate(self, id):
    return id and re.compile("Grid_exdate_").search(id)

df = pd.DataFrame()
exdate_list = []
for link in soup.find_all(id=self.get_exdate):
    exdate_list.append(link.string)

df['Grid_exdate'] = exdate_list
```

This searches the html/soup for everything starting with `Grid_exdate_` using `re.compile`. Then add the results to the dataframe. So I just created a `re.compile` search for each of the required fields and added them all to the dataframe with the correct column headings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) from docs:

> This function searches for `<table>` elements and only for `<tr>` and `<th>` rows and `<td>` elements within each `<tr>` or `<th>` element in the table. `<td>` stands for “table data”.

So  before using your file you need to wrap it with `<table>` tag:

```
<table>
your html
</table>
```

then use first element because `read_html` reads tables from html to list:

```
df = pd.read_html('file.html')

In [444]: df[0]
Out[444]:
            0     1     2   3           4          5
0   2/15/2005  Cash  0.08  --   2/17/2005  3/10/2005
1  11/15/2004  Cash  3.08  --  11/17/2004  12/2/2004
```

**EDIT**

If you want to rename columns:

```
df1 = df[0]
df1.columns = ["Grid_exdate", "Cash", "Grid_CashAmount", "Grid_DeclDate", "Grid_RecDate", "Grid_PayDate"]
```

You'll have `'Cash'` column because you have it as separate table cell:

```
In [494]: df1
Out[494]:
  Grid_exdate  Cash  Grid_CashAmount Grid_DeclDate Grid_RecDate Grid_PayDate
0   2/15/2005  Cash             0.08            --    2/17/2005    3/10/2005
1  11/15/2004  Cash             3.08            --   11/17/2004    12/2/2004
```

You then could drop 'Cash' column or edit your initial table

```
In [496]: df1.drop('Cash', axis=1)
Out[496]:
  Grid_exdate  Grid_CashAmount Grid_DeclDate Grid_RecDate Grid_PayDate
0   2/15/2005             0.08            --    2/17/2005    3/10/2005
1  11/15/2004             3.08            --   11/17/2004    12/2/2004
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want use pandas `read_html`, you can parse it more complicated:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

table = BeautifulSoup(open('test.html','r').read())

#generate header from first tr
h   = [[td.span.get('id') for td in row.select('td') if td.span != None ]
             for row in table.findAll('tr')]
#remove empty lists
h = [x for x in h if x != []]               
header = h[0]
print header
['Grid_exdate_43', 'Grid_CashAmount_43', 'Grid_DeclDate_43', 'Grid_RecDate_43', 'Grid_PayDate_43']

#if generating header is problematic, you can specify them
#header = ['Grid_exdate', 'Grid_CashAmount', 'Grid_DeclDate', 'Grid_RecDate', 'Grid_PayDate' ]

#get content of table, remove td with text Cash 
body   = [[td.text.strip() for td in row.select('td') if td.text.strip() != 'Cash']
             for row in table.findAll('tr')]
#remove empty lists
body = [x for x in body if x != []]                 

cols = zip(*body)

tbl_d  = {name:col for name, col in zip(header,cols)}

df = pd.DataFrame(tbl_d, columns = header)
```

```
print df
  Grid_exdate_43 Grid_CashAmount_43 Grid_DeclDate_43 Grid_RecDate_43  \
0      2/15/2005               0.08               --       2/17/2005   
1     11/15/2004               3.08               --      11/17/2004   

  Grid_PayDate_43  
0       3/10/2005  
1       12/2/2004  

#remove last 3 chars of column name
#more rename info:
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-3], inplace=True)
#convert columns to datetime columns
df['Grid_exdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Grid_exdate'])
df['Grid_RecDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Grid_RecDate'])
df['Grid_PayDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Grid_PayDate'])

print df

  Grid_exdate Grid_CashAmount Grid_DeclDate Grid_RecDate Grid_PayDate
0  2005-02-15            0.08            --   2005-02-17   2005-03-10
1  2004-11-15            3.08            --   2004-11-17   2004-12-02
```