# Adding Column Headers to new pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a new pandas dataframe from a previous dataframe using the `.groupby` and `.size` methods.

```
[in] results = df.groupby(["X", "Y", "Z", "F"]).size()

[out]
    9   27/02/2016  1   N   326
    9   27/02/2016  1   S   332
    9   27/02/2016  2   N   280
    9   27/02/2016  2   S   353
    9   27/02/2016  3   N   177
```

This behaves as expected, however the result is a dataframe with no column headers.

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas) question states that the following adds column names to the generated dataframe

```
[in] results.columns = ["X","Y","Z","F","Count"]
```

However, this does not seem to have any impact at all.

```
[out]
        9   27/02/2016  1   N   326
        9   27/02/2016  1   S   332
        9   27/02/2016  2   N   280
        9   27/02/2016  2   S   353
        9   27/02/2016  3   N   177
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing are your grouped columns as the index, if you call `reset_index` then it restores the column names

so

```
results = df.groupby(["X", "Y", "Z", "F"]).size()
results.reset_index()
```

should work

```
In [11]:
df.groupby(["X","Y","Z","F"]).size()

Out[11]:
X  Y           Z  F
9  27/02/2016  1  N    1
                  S    1
               2  N    1
                  S    1
               3  N    1
dtype: int64

In [12]:    
df.groupby(["X","Y","Z","F"]).size().reset_index()

Out[12]:
   X           Y  Z  F  0
0  9  27/02/2016  1  N  1
1  9  27/02/2016  1  S  1
2  9  27/02/2016  2  N  1
3  9  27/02/2016  2  S  1
4  9  27/02/2016  3  N  1
```

Additionally you can achieve what you want by using `count`:

```
In [13]:
df.groupby(["X","Y","Z","F"]).count().reset_index()

Out[13]:
   X           Y  Z  F  Count
0  9  27/02/2016  1  N      1
1  9  27/02/2016  1  S      1
2  9  27/02/2016  2  N      1
3  9  27/02/2016  2  S      1
4  9  27/02/2016  3  N      1
```

You could also pass param `as_index=False` here:

```
In [15]:
df.groupby(["X","Y","Z","F"], as_index=False).count()

Out[15]:
   X           Y  Z  F  Count
0  9  27/02/2016  1  N      1
1  9  27/02/2016  1  S      1
2  9  27/02/2016  2  N      1
3  9  27/02/2016  2  S      1
4  9  27/02/2016  3  N      1
```

This is normally fine but some aggregate functions will bork if you try to use aggregation methods on columns whose `dtypes` cannot be aggregated, for instance if you have `str` dtypes and you decide to call `mean` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `as_index=False` parameter for the `.groupby()` function:

```
results = df.groupby(["X", "Y", "Z", "F"], as_index=False).size().rename(columns={0:'Count'})
```