# Adding headers to processed dataframe in Panda's

Tags: python, csv, pandas

[Here](http://github.com/ecenm/data/blob/master/sorted.csv.zip) is my dataset.

I am creating a new pandas dataframe (ptocol) from a previous dataframe (data) using the .groupby and .size methods as shown below.  This behaves as expected, however the result is a dataframe with no column headers.

I tried and checked the solution discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038733/adding-column-headers-to-new-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a very long time. But it doesn't work for me. Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

data = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
ptocol = data.groupby(["Protocol"], as_index=False).size().rename(columns={0:'NumOfPackets'}) # dosn't work
#ptocol = data.groupby(["Protocol"], as_index=False).count() #doesn't work
print ptocol
ptocol.to_csv('protocol.csv')
```

**Actual result (protocol.csv):**

```
0x200e,26
ARP,100746
ATMTCP,48
BOOTP,123
BZR,4
...
...
```

**expected result (protocol.csv):**

```
Protocol,NumOfPackets
0x200e,26
ARP,100746
ATMTCP,48
BOOTP,123
BZR,4
...
...
```

Any ideas/suggestion are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.size()` returns a Series object, you can use `reset_index()` to transform it to a data frame, try this instead:

```
ptocol = data.groupby("Protocol").size().rename('NumOfPackets').reset_index()
ptocol.to_csv('protocol.cv', index = False)
```

This gives something like this, not the same data as yours but the format is what you are looking for:

```
Symbol,NUM
A,5
AA,5
AAAP,5
```