# how can I include the header?

Tags: python, pandas

Quite new into pandas, I have generated a new column from division of  last_value /first_value  row in a this df.

```
df=
     data1 data2 
A      4    3
B      4    3
C      5    3
D      1    9
```

I generated this new column (with no headers)

```
new_column= df.loc[D]/df.loc[A]

new_column=
data1   0.25
data2   3
```

I have tried to add a header 'results' through :

```
new_column.rename(columns={0 :'results'}, inplace=True)
new_column.rename(columns={'0' :'results'}, inplace=True)
new_column['results']= df.loc[D]/df.loc[A]


print (new_column)
```

From the research done, nothing seems to work/adapt:

[Adding Column Headers to new pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038733/adding-column-headers-to-new-pandas-dataframe)

The result is the same without any headers.How can I include the header?

What I am looking for is :

```
       results
data1   0.25
data2   3
```

In short the new_column with the header 'results'

Comment: can you post your desired data set? it's not very clear what are you after...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm editing this on my phone, so excuse the funky formatting, but does this do it?

```
new = pd.DataFrame({'results':df.loc[D]/df.loc[A]})
```

Comment: great that is what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

`new_column` is a `pd.Series`, it doesn't have "columns", it does however have a `name`:

```
>>> new_column = df.loc['D']/df.loc['A']
>>> new_column
data1    0.25
data2    3.00
dtype: float64
```

By default, it doesn't have one if constructed this way, but:

```
>>> new_column.rename('results', inplace=True)
data1    0.25
data2    3.00
Name: results, dtype: float64
```

You want a `pandas.DataFrame`, so you could this instead of the above:

```
>>> new_column = (df.loc['D']/df.loc['A']).to_frame()
>>> new_column
          0
data1  0.25
data2  3.00
```

And now your attempts work:

```
>>> new_column.rename(columns={0 :'results'}, inplace=True)
>>> new_column
       results
data1     0.25
data2     3.00
```

Or, you could have done it in one, fell, swoop:

```
>>> new_column = pd.DataFrame((df.loc['D']/df.loc['A']), columns=['results'])
>>> new_column
       results
data1     0.25
data2     3.00
```

#### Edit to add suggestion by @MaxU

Or perhaps the easiest way is as suggested by MaxU:

```
>>> (df.loc['D']/df.loc['A']).to_frame('results')
       results
data1     0.25
data2     3.00
```

Comment: what about `(df.loc['D']/df.loc['A']).to_frame('results')`? ;-)

Comment: @MaxU Nice, I was unaware `to_frame` took a `name` parameter!