# Loop over columns to cleanse the values

Tags: python, pandas

I have many columns in my pandas data frame which I want to cleanse with a specific method. I want to see if there is a way to do this in one go.

This is what I tried and this does not work.

```
list = list(bigtable) # this list has all the columns i want to cleanse

for index in list:

   bigtable1.column = bigtable.column.str.split(',', expand=True).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.sort(x)).str.cat(sep=','), axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I should hammer this closed, but this looks like it's probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas/16667215#16667215

Comment: My bad. Please note the edit in title.

Comment: could you post a sample input data set (or columns) and desired data set, because it's not clear what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

try this should work:

```
bigtable1=pd.Dataframe()

for index in list:

   bigtable1[index] = bigtable[index].str.split(',', expand=True).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.sort(x)).str.cat(sep=','), axis=1)
```