# Rename column header from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes where 1, 2, 3 is the connection between the dataframes:

```
              1    2    3 
2016-10-03   12   10   10 
2016-10-04   4     4    5 
......

and
     name    year
1   apple    2001
2   lemon    2002
3   kiwi     1990
```

The end result should be:

```
              apple    lemon    kiwi 
2016-10-03       12       10      10 
2016-10-04        4        4       5 
......
```

I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: what's wrong with `df1.columns = df2.name`?

Comment: check also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), which does not require the two DataFrames to have the keys in the same order:

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns=df2['name'])
```