# Renaming columns on DataFrame output of pandas.concat

Tags: python, pandas

I'm construction a new DataFrame by concatenating the columns of other DataFrames, like so:

```
pairs = pd.concat([pos1['Close'], pos2['Close'], pos3['Close'], pos4['Close'], pos5['Close'],
                  pos6['Close'], pos7['Close']], axis=1)
```

I want to rename all of the columns of the `pairs` Dataframe to the symbol of the underlying securities. Is there a way to do this during the the concat method call? Reading through the docs on the method here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.concat.html didn't give me a solid answer.

Comment: You'd need to do this as a post processing step or a chained call

Comment: @EdChum So set up a list of strings and do an enumerate calling: pairs.columns.values[idx] = symbol ?

Comment: You should use `rename(columns=some_dict)` or if you know the final order then make a list comprehension and call `pairs.columns = your_list` also you can use `rename_axis`

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas?s=1|6.3872

Comment: The rename approach doesn't work because the value for all columns is 'Close', so any value passed in renames all columns simultaneously…so there has to be some use of idx.

Answer (score 22):

You can achieve the same in one go using the attribute `keys`:

```
pairs = pd.concat([pos1['Close'], pos2['Close'], pos3['Close'], pos4['Close'], pos5['Close'], pos6['Close'], pos7['Close']],  
axis=1, keys= ['JPM', 'WFC', 'BAC', 'C', 'STI', 'PNC', 'CMA'])
```

Comment: It just add a new level to my columns in my case.

Answer (score 13):

This is the approach I'm taking. Seems to fit all my requirements.

```
symbols = ['JPM', 'WFC', 'BAC', 'C', 'STI', 'PNC', 'CMA']

pairs.columns = symbols
```

Comment: You can just do `pairs.columns = symbols`, assigning directly to the underlying numpy array representation may not always work

Comment: @EdChum Can you give an example of when it won't work? Would be good to have a complete discussion on this thread.

Comment: The problem here is that `.values` returns you a np array of the underlying values, here we enter into unknown territory as we don't know if you're returned a view or a copy of the data. In general one should always use the provided methods for these kind of operations to avoid this ambiguity

Comment: @EdChum Edited to reflect that feedback