# Dynamically differencing columns in a pandas dataframe using similar column names

Tags: python, pandas

The following is the first couple of columns of a data frame, and I calculate V1_x - V1_y, V2_x - V2_y, V3_x - V3_y etc. The difference variable names differ only by the last character (either x or y)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John'], 'Address': ['xx', 'yy', 'zz','ww'], 'V1_x': [20, 21, 19, 18], 'V2_x': [233, 142, 643, 254], 'V3_x': [343, 543, 254, 543], 'V1_y': [20, 21, 19, 18], 'V2_y': [233, 142, 643, 254], 'V3_y': [343, 543, 254, 543]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
     Name Address  V1_x  V2_x  V3_x  V1_y  V2_y  V3_y
0     Tom      xx    20   233   343    20   233   343
1  Joseph      yy    21   142   543    21   142   543
2   Krish      zz    19   643   254    19   643   254
3    John      ww    18   254   543    18   254   543
```

I currently do the calculation by manually defining the column names:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df['Name'] = df['Name']
new_df['Address'] = df['Address']
new_df['Col1'] = df['V1_x']-df['V1_y']
new_df['Col1'] = df['V2_x']-df['V2_y']
new_df['Col1'] = df['V3_x']-df['V3_y']
```

Is there an approach that I can use to check if the last column names only differ by the last character and difference them if so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating column names with string and number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503845/generating-column-names-with-string-and-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a multiindex header using `.str.split` then reshape the dataframe and using `pd.DataFrame.eval` for calcuation then reshape back to original form with additional columns.  Lastly flatten the multiindex header using list comprehension with f-string formatting:

```
dfi = df.set_index(['Name', 'Address'])

dfi.columns = dfi.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

dfs = dfi.stack(0).eval('diff=x-y').unstack()
dfs.columns = [f'{j}_{i}' for i, j in dfs.columns]

dfs
```

Output:

```
                V1_x  V2_x  V3_x  V1_y  V2_y  V3_y  V1_diff  V2_diff  V3_diff
Name   Address                                                               
John   ww         18   254   543    18   254   543        0        0        0
Joseph yy         21   142   543    21   142   543        0        0        0
Krish  zz         19   643   254    19   643   254        0        0        0
Tom    xx         20   233   343    20   233   343        0        0        0
```