# python pandas rename multiple column headers the same way

Tags: python, pandas, header, rename

Considering a simple df:

```
HeaderA | HeaderB | HeaderC 
    476      4365      457
```

Is there a way to rename all columns, for example to add to all columns an "X" in the end?

```
HeaderAX | HeaderBX | HeaderCX 
    476      4365      457
```

I am concatenating multiple dataframes and want to easily differentiate the columns dependent on which dataset they came from.

Or is this the only way?

```
df.rename(columns={'HeaderA': 'HeaderAX'}, inplace=True)
```

I have over 50 column headers and ten files; so the above approach will take a long time.

Thank You

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**`pd.DataFrame.add_suffix`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html)

```
df.add_suffix('X')

   HeaderAX  HeaderBX  HeaderCX
0       476      4365       457
```

---

And the sister method
[**`pd.DataFrame.add_prefix`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)

```
df.add_prefix('X')

   XHeaderA  XHeaderB  XHeaderC
0       476      4365       457
```

---

You can also use the [**`pd.DataFrame.rename`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method and pass a function.  To accomplish the same thing:

```
df.rename(columns='{}X'.format)

   HeaderAX  HeaderBX  HeaderCX
0       476      4365       457
```

In this example, `'{}X'.format` is a function that takes a single argument and appends an `'X'`

The advantage of this method is that you can use `inplace=True` if you chose to.

Comment: @jeangelj glad I can help :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
df.columns = list(map(lambda s: s+'X', df.columns))
```

Answer (score 2):

From SO [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas?rq=1).  Let's try using a lambda function in rename:

df.rename(columns = lambda x: x+'X', inplace = True)

Answer (score 1):

```
df.columns = [column + 'X' for column in df.columns]
```