# KeyError: ('count', 'occurred at index 0')

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, d3.js

I am trying to do the example in [Use Python & Pandas to Create a D3 Force Directed Network Diagram](http://www.austintaylor.io/d3/python/pandas/2016/02/01/create-d3-chart-python-force-directed/)

But in the below line I am getting an error 'KeyError: ('count', 'occurred at index 0')'

```
 temp_links_list = list(grouped_src_dst.apply(lambda row: {"source": row['source'], "target": row['target'], "value": row['count']}, axis=1))
```

I am new in python. What is the issue here?

**Edited code**

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import re

pcap_data = pd.read_csv('C:\packet_metadata.csv', index_col='No.')
dataframe = pcap_data
src_dst = dataframe[["Source","Destination"]]
src_dst.rename(columns={"Source":"source","Destination":"target"}, inplace=True)
grouped_src_dst = src_dst.groupby(["source","target"]).size().reset_index()
grouped_src_dst.rename(columns={'count':'value'}).to_dict(orient='records')
unique_ips = pd.Index(grouped_src_dst['source']
                  .append(grouped_src_dst['target'])
                  .reset_index(drop=True).unique())
```

But

```
print(grouped_src_dst.columns.tolist())
['source', 'target', 0]
```

**Final code**

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import re

pcap_data = pd.read_csv('C:\packet_metadata.csv', index_col='No.')
dataframe = pcap_data
src_dst = dataframe[["Source","Destination"]]
src_dst.sample(10)
grouped_src_dst = src_dst.groupby(["Source","Destination"]).size().reset_index()
d={0:'value',"Source":"source","Destination":"target"}
L = grouped_src_dst.rename(columns=d)
unique_ips = pd.Index(L['source']
                  .append(L['target'])
                  .reset_index(drop=True).unique())
group_dict = {}
counter = 0
for ip in unique_ips:
breakout_ip = re.match("^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$", ip)
if breakout_ip:
    net_id = '.'.join(breakout_ip.group(1,2,3))
    if net_id not in group_dict:
        counter += 1
        group_dict[net_id] = counter
    else:
        pass


temp_links_list = list(L.apply(lambda row: {"source": row['source'], "target": row['target'], "value": row['value']}, axis=1))
```

Comment: What is `print (grouped_src_dst.columns.tolist())` ? Because it seems there is no column `count` or some whitespace like `'   count'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is problem with column name `count` - missing or some witespace like `' count'`.

```
#check columns names
print (grouped_src_dst.columns.tolist())
['count', 'source', 'target']
```

Sample:

```
grouped_src_dst = pd.DataFrame({'source':['a','s','f'], 
                                'target':['b','n','m'], 
                                'count':[0,8,4]})
print (grouped_src_dst)
   count source target
0      0      a      b
1      8      s      n
2      4      f      m

f = lambda row: {"source": row['source'], "target": row['target'], "value": row['count']}
temp_links_list = list(grouped_src_dst.apply(f, axis=1))
print (temp_links_list)
[{'value': 0, 'source': 'a', 'target': 'b'}, 
 {'value': 8, 'source': 's', 'target': 'n'}, 
 {'value': 4, 'source': 'f', 'target': 'm'}]
```

Simplier solution is rename column `count` and use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
print (grouped_src_dst.rename(columns={'count':'value'}).to_dict(orient='records'))


[{'value': 0, 'source': 'a', 'target': 'b'}, 
 {'value': 8, 'source': 's', 'target': 'n'}, 
 {'value': 4, 'source': 'f', 'target': 'm'}]
```

EDIT1:

```
pcap_data = pd.read_csv('C:\packet_metadata.csv', index_col='No.')

grouped_src_dst = pcap_data.groupby(["Source","Destination"]).size().reset_index()
d = {0:'value', "Source":"source","Destination":"target"}
L = grouped_src_dst.rename(columns=d).to_dict(orient='records')
```

Sample:

```
pcap_data = pd.DataFrame({'Source':list('aabbccdd'), 
                          'Destination':list('eertffff')})
print (pcap_data)
  Destination Source
0           e      a
1           e      a
2           r      b
3           t      b
4           f      c
5           f      c
6           f      d
7           f      d

grouped_src_dst = pcap_data.groupby(["Source","Destination"]).size().reset_index()
print (grouped_src_dst)
  Source Destination  0
0      a           e  2
1      b           r  1
2      b           t  1
3      c           f  2
4      d           f  2

d = {0:'value', "Source":"source","Destination":"target"}
L = grouped_src_dst.rename(columns=d).to_dict(orient='records')
print (L)
[{'value': 2, 'source': 'a', 'target': 'e'}, 
 {'value': 1, 'source': 'b', 'target': 'r'}, 
 {'value': 1, 'source': 'b', 'target': 't'}, 
 {'value': 2, 'source': 'c', 'target': 'f'}, 
 {'value': 2, 'source': 'd', 'target': 'f'}]
```

---

```
unique_ips = pd.Index(grouped_src_dst['Source']
                  .append(grouped_src_dst['Destination'])
                  .reset_index(drop=True).unique())

print (unique_ips)
Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'r', 't', 'f'], dtype='object')


import numpy as np

unique_ips = np.unique(grouped_src_dst[['Source','Destination']].values.ravel()).tolist()
print (unique_ips)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'r', 't']
```

Comment: My code is similar to your sample code, but where should I give grouped_src_dst.rename(columns={'count':'value'}).to_dict(orient='records'). Why do we need to convert it to dictionary

Comment: it is only standard way for rename columns - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354850/2901002)

Comment: and second `to_dict` I think pandas developers wants similar way for multiple outputs (orient='index', orient='list', orinet='records'...)

Comment: You are really close, only need replace `0` like `grouped_src_dst.rename(columns={0:'value'}).to_dict(orient='records')`

Comment: Are you sure? see edit1 - I do more changes and simplier code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147786/discussion-between-a-a-and-jezrael).