# Why can't I access a column in pandas after renaming?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

If I have a data frame and rename the column, I am unable to access the column by its new name.

See example for illustration :

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b': [10,20]})
df
   a   b
0  1  10
1  2  20
df['a']
0    1
1    2
```

Now if I rename column 'a' as in a manner suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas).

```
df.columns.values[0] = 'newname'
df
   newname   b
0        1  10
1        2  20
```

Now let's try to access the column using the 'newname'

```
 df['newname']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1797, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1804, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1084, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2851, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1572, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3824)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3704)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 686, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12280)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 694, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12231)
KeyError: 'newname'
```

Yet I can still access the column by the old name.

```
df['a']
0    1
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

It seems that I've changed the nominal name of the column, yet that change did not propagate through to the dictionary used to deference columns in the data frame structure.

QUESTION : Why is this behavior happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this approach:

```
In [131]: df.columns = ['newname'] + df.columns.tolist()[1:]

In [132]: df
Out[132]:
   newname   b
0        1  10
1        2  20
```

or:

```
In [136]: df = df.rename(columns={df.columns.tolist()[0]:'newname'})

In [137]: df
Out[137]:
   newname   b
0        1  10
1        2  20
```