# Rename the column inside csv file

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone please check for me what's wrong with my renaming command. It changes nothing on the csv file. The code that i have tried below renaming header.

```
df = pandas.read_csv('C:/JIRA Excel File.csv')
df.rename(columns=({'Custom field (Implemented Date)':'Custom field (Verified Date)'}))
df.set_index('Custom field (Verified Date)').to_csv("C:/JIRA Excel File/Done.csv", index=None)
```

I want column Custom field (Implemented Date) CHANGE to Custom field
(verified Date), but the column still doesn't change.

**Original CSV.file**

[image: Click Here]

Now the KeyError: 'Custom field (Implemented Date)' is not execute anymore.
Just after I run this code.

The output will display as below.

[image]

Comment: are you wanting to change the column name?

Comment: yaa, I want it to delete column verified date and rename implemented date to verified date. So, the output will display Issue Type and Verified date, which I rename the implemented date.

Comment: please see the updated answer. Hope this will help you a little bit more.

Answer (score 4):

You are not assigning the result of rename back to the dataframe. Change the 2nd line to

```
df = df.rename(columns=({'Custom field (Implemented Date)':'Custom field (Verified Date)'}))
```

Comment: Hi, I've change the 2nd line code, and it gives error. 
KeyError: 'Custom field (Implemented Date)'

Comment: Can you post what are you getting with df.columns after executing df = pandas.read_csv('C:/JIRA Excel File.csv')? Key error means that the column name that you are trying to change is not 'Custom field (Implemented Date)'

Answer (score 4):

you can call rename function with external parameter `inplace=True`

```
df.rename(columns={'Custom field (Implemented Date)': 'Custom field (Verified Date)'}, inplace=True)
```

For more see [pandas.DataFrame.rename](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

**Update:**
from your comment and updated question

```
# considering a sample csv from  your description and the df is.
''' 
  Issue Type Custom field (Verified Date) Custom field (Implemented Date)
0    issue-1               varified-date1               Implemented-Date1
1    issue-2               varified-date2               Implemented-Date2
'''
# first delete the 'Custom field (Verified Date)' column
del df['Custom field (Verified Date)']
'''
  Issue Type Custom field (Implemented Date)
0    issue-1               Implemented-Date1
1    issue-2               Implemented-Date2
'''
# rename the column 'Custom field (Implemented Date)' to 'Custom field (Verified Date)'
df.rename(columns={'Custom field (Implemented Date)': 'Custom field (Verified Date)'}, inplace=True)
'''
Issue Type Custom field (Verified Date)
0    issue-1            Implemented-Date1
1    issue-2            Implemented-Date2
'''
df.set_index('Custom field (Verified Date)').to_csv("Done.csv", index=None)
```

And after all this I get the output in file as you describe above with out any error.

Comment: yaa but still even I replaced with your code, and actually all of the command I take also with the same link that you refers. At the end it will delete 'Custom field (Implemented Date)' as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
renamed_df=df.rename(columns={'Custom field (Implemented Date)':'Custom field (Verified Date)'})
renamed_df.to_csv("C:/JIRA Excel File/Done.csv", index=None)
```