# Iterating through a Dataframe to get values based on another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets Say I have the following DataFrames:

DATAFRAME 1

```
    CFOP    Vendas
0   5101    Venda
1   6101    Venda
2   6107    Venda
3   6118    Venda
4   6109    Venda
```

DATAFRAME 2

```
    Name    CFOP    Vendas
0   John    5101    10,00
1   Lea     7008    20,00
2   Anthony 6107    15,00
3   Frank   7000    17,00
4   TOM     6109    21,00
```

I want to make a third Dataframe only if row 1 of Dataframe 1 mathces row 2 from Dataframe 2.

So, the final answer should be:

```
    Name    CFOP    Vendas
0   John    5101    10,00
2   Anthony 6107    15,00
4   TOM     6109    21,00
```

I am stuck, I just could get this code which I know it is wrong:

```
vendas_somente = []

for row in df_entrada:
    if df_entrada['cfo'] in df_venda['CFOP']:
        vendas_somente.append(row)

vendas_somente(10)
```

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create it with an inner merge

```
In[38]: d1[['CFOP']].merge(d2,how='inner',on='CFOP')
Out[38]: 

   CFOP     Name Vendas
0  5101     John  10,00
1  6107  Anthony  15,00
2  6109      TOM  21,00
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `isin`

```
df2.loc[df2.CFOP.isin(df1.CFOP)]
Out[573]: 
      Name  CFOP Vendas
0     John  5101  10,00
2  Anthony  6107  15,00
4      TOM  6109  21,00
```

Comment: Can you do me a favor and check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46192213/2336654) and upvote if you think it's worth it?  Thanks!

Comment: @piRSquared sure ：）