# Inserting a header row for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have just started python and am trying to rewrite one of my perl scripts in python. Essentially, I had a long script to convert a csv to json.

I've tried to import my csv into a pandas dataframe, and wanted to insert a header row at the top, since my csv lacks that.
Code:

```
import pandas
db=pandas.read_csv("netmedsdb.csv",header=None)
db
```

Output:

```
0   1   2   3
0   3M CAVILON NO STING BARRIER FILM SPRAY 28ML OTC 0   Rs.880.00   3M INDIA LTD
1   BACTI BAR SOAP 75GM OTC Rs.98.00    6TH SKIN PHARMACEUTICALS PVT LTD
2   KWIKNIC MINT FLAVOUR 4MG CHEW GUM TABLET 30'S   NICOTINE    Rs.180.00   A S V LABORATORIES INDIA PVT LTD
3   RIFAGO 550MG TABLET 10'S    RIFAXIMIN 550MG Rs.298.00   AAREEN HEALTHCARE
4   999 OIL 60ML    AYURVEDIC MEDICINE  Rs.120.00   AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
5   AKASH SOAP 75GM AYURVEDIC PRODUCT   Rs.80.00    AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
6   GROW CARE OIL 100ML AYURVEDIC MEDICINE  Rs.190.00   AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
7   GROW CARE OIL 100ML AYURVEDIC MEDICINE  Rs.190.00   AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
8   RHUNS OIL 30ML  AYURVEDIC   Rs.50.00    AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
9   VILLO CAPSULE 10'S  AYURVEDIC MEDICINE  Rs.70.00    AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
10  VITAWIN FORTE CAPSULE 10'S  AYURVEDIC MEDICINE  Rs.150.00   AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
```

I wrote the following code to insert the first element at row 0,coloumn 0:

```
db.insert(loc=0,column='0',value='Brand')
db
```

Output:

```
0   0   1   2   3
0   Brand   3M CAVILON NO STING BARRIER FILM SPRAY 28ML OTC 0   Rs.880.00   3M INDIA LTD
1   Brand   BACTI BAR SOAP 75GM OTC Rs.98.00    6TH SKIN PHARMACEUTICALS PVT LTD
2   Brand   KWIKNIC MINT FLAVOUR 4MG CHEW GUM TABLET 30'S   NICOTINE    Rs.180.00   A S V LABORATORIES INDIA PVT LTD
3   Brand   RIFAGO 550MG TABLET 10'S    RIFAXIMIN 550MG Rs.298.00   AAREEN HEALTHCARE
4   Brand   999 OIL 60ML    AYURVEDIC MEDICINE  Rs.120.00   AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
5   Brand   AKASH SOAP 75GM AYURVEDIC PRODUCT   Rs.80.00    AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
6   Brand   GROW CARE OIL 100ML AYURVEDIC MEDICINE  Rs.190.00   AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
7   Brand   GROW CARE OIL 100ML AYURVEDIC MEDICINE  Rs.190.00   AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
8   Brand   RHUNS OIL 30ML  AYURVEDIC   Rs.50.00    AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
9   Brand   VILLO CAPSULE 10'S  AYURVEDIC MEDICINE  Rs.70.00    AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
10  Brand   VITAWIN FORTE CAPSULE 10'S  AYURVEDIC MEDICINE  Rs.150.00   AAKASH PHARMACEUTICALS
```

But unfortunately I got the word "Brand" inserted at coloumn 0 in all rows.

I'm trying to add the header coloumns "Brand", "Generic", "Price", "Company"

Comment: Need `db=pandas.read_csv("netmedsdb.csv",header=None, names=["Brand", "Generic", "Price", "Company", 'col'....])`

Comment: Or, to rename after importing, use `db.columns = ["Brand", "Generic", "Price", "Company"]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need parameter `names` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) only:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""a,b,10,d
e,f,45,r
"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'netmedsdb.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), names=["Brand", "Generic", "Price", "Company"])
print (df)
  Brand Generic  Price Company
0     a       b     10       d
1     e       f     45       r
```