# How do I rename the 1 values in a categorical variable as the header of the column?

Tags: python, pandas, header, rename

I have a Pandas DataFrame with several categorical variables (1 or 0) and I would like to rename the 1 value as per its own variable name, how to do it?

```
          Name           Achiever  Arranger  Belief  Consistency  Deliberative  
0          Alex           1.0       0.0     0.0          0.0           0.0   
13         Luke           0.0       0.0     0.0          1.0           0.0
```

I would like to return

```
          Name           Achiever  Arranger  Belief  Consistency  Deliberative  
0          Alex        Achiever      0.0     0.0          0.0           0.0   
13         Luke           0.0       0.0     0.0    Conistency          0.0
```

Comment: Are you trying to rename the columns? have you looked at this post? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas/46912050#46912050)

Comment: Consider coming up with [MCVE] to increase the chances of getting answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for col in df.columns.values:
    df[col].replace(to_replace=1, value=col, inplace=True)
```