# asking about pandas dataframe regarding the column name changes in it

Tags: python, pandas

Can somebody tell me different ways to change the name of a column in pandas data frame. I have a data frame in which i need to change the name of a column so that i can apply merge function accordingly

Comment: @RafaelC please can you provide me the link to that question so that i can find the answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas :)