# Rename pandas dataframe columns whose type is RangeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe whose columns are RangeIndex. I want to change the names.

```
import pandas as pd
>>> my_df

            0         1
Alpha    -0.1234     0.001
Beta     0.7890      0.005

>>> my_df.columns
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)
```

I want to do something like:

```
 my_df = my_df.rename({'0': 'Betas', '1': 'P-values})
```

And it should look like:

```
>>> my_df

            Betas         P-values
Alpha    -0.1234     0.001
Beta     0.7890      0.005
```

But it does not change the column names.

Comment: Use `my_df.rename(columns={0: 'Betas', 1: 'P-values'})`

Comment: you can just assign directly `my_df.columns = ['Betas', 'P-values']`

Comment: @EdChum Thank you. That also works. Which method is more efficient?

Comment: @Wen To which problem is this possibly a duplicate?

Comment: @JunSeongJang https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354850/7964527

Comment: @Wen It's not really the same problem because I am trying to rename RangeIndex, not strings. It's a SIMILAR problem, but definitely not SAME or DUPLICATE.

Comment: @JunSeongJang,  Direct assignment to columns looks more elegant.

Comment: @JunSeongJang all the function behind your problem and the tag question are same . rangeindex still can be rename using `rename` ., If you like i will open it.

Comment: direct naming doesn't work for me. My df is one row created from a list, then transposed. When I try direct naming, e.g. `my_df.columns = ['Betas', 'P-values']` it results in `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' ` (yet `type(my_df)` is `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple and straightforward.

```
my_df.rename(columns = { '0': 'Betas', '1': 'P-values' }, inplace=True)
```

Even nicer as borrowed from **Edchum**

```
my_df.columns = ['Betas', 'P-values']
```