# Python:How to rename columns with string and number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a Dataframe like this

```
df:
   X  Y  Z
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
```

If I want to rename the columns with a string and number in the range(0, 3) like this

```
df:
  new_0  new_1  new_2
0     1      0      0
1     0      1      0
2     0      0      1
```

What can I do?

Actually, in my case I have about 73 columns which should be renamed, so I think that I can not just rename each column one by one.

Thanks~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: Something like: `df.columns = [f'new_{n}' for n in enumerate(df.columns)]` ?

Comment: Actually, in my case I have about 73 columns which should be renamed, so I think that I can not just rename each column one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have a function `rename()` to map your old column to new column, then it will be as easy as this:

```
df.columns = [rename(c) for c in df.columns]
```

I do not know if you mean this, but if you simply want to *renumber* your columns, this is what to do:

```
df.columns = ["new_%d" % i for i,_ in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

Comment: Yes, the answer  you gave me is what I really want . Thank you very much. =))

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pandas / NumPy functionality:

```
df.columns = np.arange(df.shape[1])
df = df.add_prefix('new_')
```

Or you can use a list comprehension with f-strings (Python 3.6; [PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
df.columns = [f'new_{i}' for i in range(df.shape[1])]
```