# Rename a df column by that have same names by iterating column indexes-pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns, rename

I have a `pandas` data frame like this,

```
   Name     Not_Included  Quantity Not_Included  
0  Auto     DNS           10       DNS
1  NaN      DNS           12       DNS
2  Rtal     DNS           18       DNS
3  NaN      DNS           14       DNS
4  Indl     DNS           16       DNS
5  NaN      DNS           18       DNS
```

Now, I want to rename `Not_Included` using data frame's column indexes. So, I get the output like this,

```
       Name     Not_Included_1  Quantity Not_Included_3  
    0  Auto     DNS             10       DNS
    1  NaN      DNS             12       DNS
    2  Rtal     DNS             18       DNS
    3  NaN      DNS             14       DNS
    4  Indl     DNS             16       DNS
    5  NaN      DNS             18       DNS
```

I tried the following,

```
for c,v in enumerate(s_df):
    if v == 'Not_Included':
        vi = 'Not_Included' + str(c)
        s_df.rename(columns=lambda n: n.replace(v, vi), inplace=True)
```

I get the following result,

```
    Name    Not_Included31  Quantity  Not_Included31
0   Auto    DNS             10        DNS
1   NaN     DNS             12        DNS
2   Rtal    DNS             18        DNS
3   NaN     DNS             14        DNS
4   Indl    DNS             16        DNS
5   NaN     DNS             18        DNS
```

There are [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas) to rename a whole data frame's columns, but that is not what I am looking for since I am automating some tasks. How can I get my desired output using index of columns?

Also, can I do it in list comprehension method in renaming pandas columns?

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `np.where` to set the columns, checking where it's duplicated.

```
import numpy as np

df.columns = np.where(df.columns.duplicated(),  
                      [f'{df.columns[i]}_{i}' for i in range(len(df.columns))],
                      df.columns)
```

---

Indices also have a where method:

```
df.columns = df.columns.where(~df.columns.duplicated(),
                              [f'{df.columns[i]}_{i}' for i in range(len(df.columns))])
```

#### Output:

```
   Name Not_Included  Quantity Not_Included_3
0  Auto          DNS        10            DNS
1   NaN          DNS        12            DNS
2  Rtal          DNS        18            DNS
```

Comment: this works great, I assume this is the closest to the list comprehension type of solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can works too

```
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(coluna, index) if 'Not_Included' in coluna else coluna for index, coluna in enumerate(df.columns)]
```