# Pandas: Create new dataframe based on existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

what is the most elegant way to create a new dataframe from an existing dataframe, by 1. selecting only certain columns and 2. renaming them at the same time?

For instance I have the following dataframe, where I want to pick column B, D and F and rename them into X, Y, Z

base dataframe

```
A B C D E F
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

new dataframe

```
X Y Z
2 4 6
2 4 6
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your attempts at this.

Comment: You can use a dictionary with `df.rename()` to rename a certain subset of columns and then simultaneously index with the keys. So `d = {"B": "X", "D": "Y", "F": "Z"}` and then simply do something like `new = df[list(d.keys())].rename(columns=d)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!!  Please review this -- How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and repost your question.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers - so it looks like i need to have two separate steps: 1. selection and 2. renaming. I was hoping to have something elegant like when i define a dict.

Comment: I tried something like this - but this looks not natural

df = pd.concat(
    [
    df['B'], 
    df['D'],
    df['F'],
    ],
    axis=1, keys=['x','y','z'])

Answer (score 5):

You can select and rename the columns in one line

```
df2=df[['B','D','F']].rename({'B':'X','D':'Y','F':'Z'}, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more general selection of every other column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 
                   'C':[7,8,9], 'D':[10,11,12]})

df_half = df.iloc[:, ::2]
```

with `df_half` being:

```
    A   C
0   1   7
1   2   8
2   3   9
```

You can then use the rename method mentioned in the answer by @G. Anderson or directly [assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas) to the columns:

```
df_half.columns = ['X','Y']
```

returning:

```
    X   Y
0   1   7
1   2   8
2   3   9
```