# Renaming special characters in column headers after pivoting

Tags: python, pandas

folllowing this thread: [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas). I want to use this line:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('$','')
```

The problem is I pivoted the dataframe with `df.pivot_table().to_records()`and converted it to records, now my column headers have the following syntax:
`"('content2', ':13A::STAT')"`

from this I only want to keep: `13A::STAT`, any idea to do so?

Is there any way to avoid this renaming in pivoting the dataframe?

Example dataframe (after pivoting):

```
occurance ('content2, ':13A::STAT') ('content2', '17B::ACTI')
1          4000                       Y
2            NaN                       73000
```

Expected output:

```
occurance 13A::STAT                  17B::ACTI
1          4000                       Y
2            NaN                       73000
```

Comment: `df1 =  pd.DataFrame(df.pivot_table(index='occurance', columns="random", values=['content2'], aggfunc = lambda x: x.tolist() if len(list(x)) > 1 else x.iat[0]).to_records())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit `MultiIndex` in column if omit `[]` in `['content2']`:

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index='occurance', 
                     columns="random", 
                     values='content2', 
                     aggfunc = lambda x: x.tolist() if len(list(x)) > 1 else x.iat[0])
        .to_records())
```

Comment: @PV8 - yes, exaclty. If multiple columns then use `df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)`

Comment: and then `.to_records()`