# Renaming a subset of the columns in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to rename specific columns in a `pandas.DataFrame` so I can `concat` it with a similar dataframe. The code I ran is compiling but it doesn't successfully rename the columns.

```py
df4.rename(columns={"Level1":"PctLevel1","Level2":"PctLevel2","Level3":"PctLevel3","Level4":"PctLevel4"})
```

[image]

Comment: Be sure to reassign back to df4.  For example, `df4 = df4.rename(...... `

Comment: or `df4.rename(..., inplace=True)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming column names in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to reassign the code to `df4`.

```py
df4 = df4.rename(columns={"Level1":"PctLevel1","Level2":"PctLevel2","Level3":"PctLevel3","Level4":"PctLevel4"})
```

Likewise, you can set the `inplace` argument to `True`.

```py
df4.rename(columns={"Level1":"PctLevel1","Level2":"PctLevel2","Level3":"PctLevel3","Level4":"PctLevel4"}, inplace=True)
```