# Renaming columns in a dataframe - Python

Tags: python

Hi I have the following dataframe and I would like to change the name of column.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
Hollande    35  29  68  88  82  74  47  26  12  4
Rues-Basses-Fusterie    0   0   8   7   5   4   8   1   0   0
```

Instead of having 0 1 2 , I would like to get a range like that:

```
    0-9  10-19  20-29
Hollande    35  29  68  88  82  74  47  26  12  4
Rues-Basses-Fusterie    0   0   8   7   5   4   8   1   0   0
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: But you still want 10 column names `0-9 ... 90-99`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: yes 0-9 to 90-99 @myradio

Comment: See my answer, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rename all the columns in the `df` dataframe, as @RamWill pointed out, it's best to use [the rename method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), with an anonymous function:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: f"{int(x) * 10}-{int(x) * 10 + 9}")
```

You can also add the `inplace=True` argument, which means that the original data frame is modified, and no copy is created.

The new columns:

```
> df.columns                                                                                
Index(['0-9', '10-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', ...], dtype='object')
```

Comment: @Dodo3 if it works, then consider accepting the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the documentation.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

In your example you could do

```
df.rename(columns={"0": "0-9", "1": "10-19" ... , "9": "90-99"})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the columns renamed in the way you showed only or the first three (but you don't want to change the number of columns) you can do something like this assuming your data frame is called `yourDataFrame`,

```
data_top = yourDataFrame.columns
newcols = []
for a in data_top.astype(int):
    newcols.append(str(a*10) + '-' + str(a*10+9))
yourDataFrame.columns = newcols
```

Using this piece of code you can rename the columns in that way for many *pandas dataframes* independently  of the number of columns that they have.