# Renaming a range of columns in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am trying to perform calculations on a huge data frame with column names such as `Std 1`, `Std 2`, ..., `Std 8760`. Given that Python doesn't recognize spaces `(' ')`, I would like to change these names, but using functions such as `df.rename` or `df.replace` will either be time-consuming since I will have to specify the new names of all columns or will attribute the same name to all the columns(which I don't want).

Also, I tried using `df.columns.str.replace(' ','_')` to get rid of the spaces and keeping the names same but I have an output as:

```py
Index([u'_J_a_h_r_', u'_i_d___a_g_s___l_k_', u'_H_o_e_h_e___i_n___m_',
       u'_S_t_d_ _1_', u'_S_t_d_ _2_', u'_S_t_d___1_', u'_S_t_d_ _4_',
       u'_S_t_d_ _5_', u'_S_t_d_ _6_', u'_S_t_d_ _7_',
       ...
       u'_S_t_d_ _8_7_7_5_', u'_S_t_d_ _8_7_7_6_', u'_S_t_d_ _8_7_7_7_',
       u'_S_t_d_ _8_7_7_8_', u'_S_t_d_ _8_7_7_9_', u'_S_t_d_ _8_7_8_0_',
       u'_S_t_d_ _8_7_8_1_', u'_S_t_d_ _8_7_8_2_', u'_S_t_d_ _8_7_8_3_',
       u'_S_t_d___8_7_6_4_'],
      dtype='object', length=8787)
```

which doesn't solve my issue because I can still see a space in between "Std" and the figure that follows.

Comment: Can you please paste original dataframe and expected

Comment: The replace you are doing is not in-place. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas

Comment: What do you mean by "python doesn't recognise spaces"? You can use spaces everywhere except for variables' naming.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the best way to do it, but I would do something like this:

```py
df_cols = df.columns.tolist()
map = str.maketrans({' ':'_'})
new_df_cols = [col.translate(map) for col in df_cols]

df.columns = new_df_cols
```