# Rename columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to change column names with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd


jeopardy = pd.read_csv('/Users/adamshaw/Desktop/Coding/jeopardy_starting/jeopardy.csv')

jeopardy = jeopardy.rename(columns={' Air Date': 'Air_Date',
                                    ' Round': 'Round'}, inplace=True)

print(jeopardy)
```

I am getting the following output:

```
>>> None
```

How do I properly rename the columns?

these are the columns

```
Show Number    int64 
 Air Date      object
 Round         object
 Category      object
 Value         object
 Question      object
 Answer        object
```

Comment: either do `jeopardy = jeopardy.rename(...)` without `inplace` or remove `jeopardy = `.

Comment: @QuangHoangThank you!

Comment: `df.rename(..., inplace=True)` returns `None`, which you then reassign back to the dataframe. Hence your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `inplace=True` option when renaming your columns. This returns nothing (`None` type) which you are assigning to the `jeopardy` variable.

Try removing the `inplace=True` or don't reassign it to `jeopardy`. So either

```
jeopardy = jeopardy.rename(columns={' Air Date': 'Air_Date',
                                    ' Round': 'Round'})
```

or

```
jeopardy.rename(columns={' Air Date': 'Air_Date',
                         ' Round': 'Round'}, inplace=True)
```