# Can't Rename Columns of Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I can't seem to rename my columns in a dataframe.

I tried this:  `df2.columns['Rating','Spread','Cnt']`

When I look at the dataframe, the `Cnt` is not there.

I also tried this: `df2.rename(columns={'Rating','Spread','Cnt'}, inplace=True)`

Again, after I run the script, the `Cnt` doesn't show up.  All I have is the first two field names; the third one keeps dropping off.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a dictionary to the columns argument in the rename function, like this:

```
df.rename(columns={"old_name": "new_name"})
```

[Check the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df2.rename(columns={'OldName1':'Rating','OldName2':'Spread','OldName3':'Cnt'}, inplace=True)
```

Also check this out

[Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell pandas what you want to change the name to.

```
df = df.rename(columns={'some_column': 'new_column'}, axis=1)
```

Comment: FYI, `axis=1` is redundant in this case since you have passed `columns` as an argument