# pd.read_csv:comment sign in header line

Tags: python, pandas, file-io, comments

I try to import the file `data.csv` into a `pd.DataFrame` where the column names are placed in a commented line. Using `data = pd.read_csv ('data.csv', sep = ',', skiprows = 1, thousands = None, decimal = '.')` doesn't remove the comment sign (`//`) from the header. When I say `comment = '//'`, I don't get the column names, which can vary from file to file.

### How do I remove the comment sign from the first column name?

#### My `data.csv`:

```
//general comment, shouldn't pe parsed
//<d_d>,<a_d>,<a_a>
7199.71,173.965,7279.85
5671.23,1576.78,5272.2
6905.44,-1008.56,6864.76
7701.41,-90.0966,8611.31
7253.81,-377.103,2863.48
4745.01,1951.36,4020.75
```

#### The resulting `pd.DataFrame`:

```py
      //<d_d>      <a_d>     <a_a>
0     7199.71   173.9650   7279.85
1     5671.23  1576.7800   5272.20
2     6905.44 -1008.5600   6864.76
3     7701.41   -90.0966   8611.31
4     7253.81  -377.1030   2863.48
5     4745.01  1951.3600   4020.75
```

Comment: skiprows=1 if it's always the first row. if it's not then you're out of luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: @cs95 As far as I can see, this doesn't play a role (yet) for my specific task I'm facing  But it's still a goot point you made.

Answer (score -1):

If we have a dataframe, `data`, that looks like this:

```
   //col1  col2
0       1     1
1       2     2
2       3     3
3       4     4
```

And then we do this:

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.replace('//','')
```

We will get this:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     2     2
2     3     3
3     4     4
```

Comment: The problem lies before you actually get the column names, right now the comment is read in as the column names. So your solution would not work

Comment: This doesn't explain how the data is read (to remove the comment line without the header) which is why I suspect somebody downvoted this