# Skipping the first column while renaming column using for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

The ask is simple, for renaming multiple dataframe's with a single code I have written the below but when I am using the code the column which contains the primary key is also getting renamed what I want my code to do is to skip the first column and rename the rest.

Codes have been provided below for better understanding of what I am trying to achieve:

```
import pandas as pd

USA = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Rage\Desktop\usa.xlsx")
BRA = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Rage\Desktop\usa.xlsx")
CAN = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Rage\Desktop\usa.xlsx")


df_dict = {"USA":USA, "BRA":BRA, "CAN":CAN}

for name, df in df_dict.items():
        df.columns = df.columns + "_" + name
```

Which gives me the below output:

```
Primary Key_CAN local stat_CAN  valid stat_CAN  valid date_CAN
123                Approved        completed      2018-02-02
554                Restrict        pending        2020-06-05
789                Declined        pending        2016-08-07
```

Which is perfect but with one problem I want the loop to skip the first column that is "Primary key"
Making my expected output to be below:

```
Primary Key   local stat_CAN      valid stat_CAN valid date_CAN
123                Approved        completed      2018-02-02
554                Restrict        pending        2020-06-05
789                Declined        pending        2016-08-07
```

Comment: there is no difference between your expected output and the output you got. could you have a look at your post

Comment: @sammywemmy The `Primary Key_CAN` appears to be different.

Comment: @sammywemmy the diff is _CAN

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq I dont want the Primary Key column to change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq no Mateen but Mohit Sharma answered my query thanks for the the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split the `columns` index in 2 sublists and only change the second one:

```
df.columns = [df.columns[0]] + (df.columns[1:] + '_' + 'CAN').tolist()
```

Comment: Loved this answer too :)

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you

```
for name, df in df_dict.items():
        new_col = {c:c+"_"+name for c in df.columns[1:]}
        df.rename(columns=new_col, inplace = True)
```

Comment: 1 question can u please explain new_col = {c:c+"_"+name for c in df.columns[1:]} kind of a newbie here

Comment: @ragethewolf That's called a "dictionary comprehension". Read up on "list comprehensions" if you're not familiar.

Comment: its a dict comprehension, in simple terms:

`new_col = {}
for c in df.columns[1:]:    # it will iterate through columns excluding 1st
    new_col[c] = c+"_"+name`
dict will be created with key (old names) and value (new names)