# Rename headers - 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am trying to rename my columns from a df exported from pandas by doing a Header array like this.

```
Header_1 = [ 'Time', 'Tx/Rx', 'Channel', 'ID', 'Bits', 'A', 'B' ]
Frame_1 = Frame_1.rename(columns = Header_1)
```

but I get the following `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

I know that I can name my headers directly from pandas as:

```
df = pd.read_csv('df.txt', header = 15, sep=' ',
                    names = ['Time', 'Tx/Rx', 'Channel', 'ID', 'Bits', 'A', 'B'])
```

but because my df is split into 2 different bytes with different IDs I exported the df and made two dfs, one for each byte frame by the name of the ID. They are like this:

```
14:12:59:0190   Rx        1     0010    8   185    0.0     
14:12:59:2150   Rx        1     0011    8   138    184.0
14:12:59:4110   Rx        1     0010    8   185    0.0
14:12:59:6070   Rx        1     0011    8   135    184.0
14:12:59:8030   Rx        1     0010    8   185    0.0
14:12:59:9990   Rx        1     0011    8   135    184.0
```

And want them like this:

```
     Time      Tx/Rx   Channel   ID   Bits   A       
14:12:59:0190   Rx        1     0010    8   185   0.0      
14:12:59:4110   Rx        1     0010    8   185   0.0
14:12:59:8030   Rx        1     0010    8   185   0.0

     Time      Tx/Rx   Channel   ID   Bits   B 
14:12:59:2150   Rx        1     0011    8   138  184.0
14:12:59:6070   Rx        1     0011    8   135  184.0
14:12:59:9990   Rx        1     0011    8   135  184.0
```

And I split them like this:

```
Frame_1 = df.loc[df['ID'] == '0010']
Frame_2 = df.loc[df['ID'] == '0011']
```

So now I have the proper df for each "ID" but I cannot name the headers accordingly for each byte :(

Comment: Frame_1.columns = Header_1 should work in your case.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas

Answer (score 3):

`pd.DataFrame.rename(columns = mapper)` expects `mapper` to be a dictionary or a callable. A list is neither of them, hence the error.

What you need is just:

```
Frame_1.columns = Header_1
```

Because you can directly assign an iterable to the `columns` attribute of a DataFrame.

Comment: The word colums should be change to columns. I can not edit, because stackoverflow said the change is less than 6 characters.

Comment: @everfight: Damned typos... Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your dataframe columns like this.

```
Header_1 = [ 'Time', 'Tx/Rx', 'Channel', 'ID', 'Bits', 'A', 'B' ]
Frame_1.columns = Header_1
```

Answer (score 0):

it takes dict `Frame_1.rename(columns={'old_name_1': 'new_name_1', 'old_name_2': 'new_name_2'})`

From docs:
**columns** dict-like or function
*Alternative to specifying axis (mapper, axis=1 is equivalent to columns=mapper).*

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Answer (score 0):

use ZIP

```
header = ['share','depmap-Ense','Ense-depmap']
df.rename(dict(zip(df.columns,header)),axis=0)
```