# Replace column names with quotations with no quotations

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace my column names that have quotations and simply remove the quotations but when I try this:

```
for x in df.columns:
    x = x.replace('"', '')
    print(x)
```

Nothing happens and the quotations are still there.

Comment: That's replacing the text in the loop variable without actually modifying the columns. Try using a list comprehension and assign back to df.columns.

Comment: @cs95 If you have an answer please provide one, thanks.

Comment: Sure, [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61815404/4909087), this is arguably better than using a list comprehension, but that's just me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
cols = [column_name.replace('"','') for column_name in df.columns] 
df.columns = cols
```

CODE

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],'"b"':[3,4]})
print('BEFORE')
print(df)
cols = [column_name.replace('"','') for column_name in df.columns] 
df.columns = cols
print('AFTER')
print(df)
```

OUTPUT

```
BEFORE
   a  "b"
0  1    3
1  2    4
AFTER
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove it by writing the following code:

```
col=[]
for x in df.columns:
    x = x.replace('"', '')
    col.append(x)

df.columns=col
```

To know more about column renaming: Check this [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

One canonical solution to this problem is using pandas `str.replace` on the header directly (this is "vectorized"):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2], '"b"': [3, 4]})
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('"', '')

df

   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```