# Using pandas to read a column name differently

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have built a random forest model using sklearn and python to predict 'pages' from various 'size' features. In my testing and training data, the column headers are 'pages' and 'size', but in my new data I want to feed through my model to get the predictions, the column headers are 'p' and 's', rather than 'pages' and 'size'. I was wondering if there is anyway to read these as 'pages' and 'size' so that my model works correctly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column with new name to original dataframe and drop the old ones.

```
df['p'] = df['pages']

df['s'] = df['sizes']

df = df.drop(['pages','sizes'],axis=1)
```

Comment: instead of doubling the size of the dataframe, then splitting it, you could also just rename the columns

Comment: Yes, how do I rename them?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use df.rename:

```
df.rename(columns={'p':'pages', 's', 'sizes'}
```

I hope this will help you!