# Change column names of Pandas dataframes contained in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of Pandas dataframes:

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
```

The dataframes have the same column names; let's call them "col1", "col2" and "col3".

How can I change the column names to "colnew1", "colnew2" and "colnew3", without using a loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: List comprehension and using inplace.  `[d.rename(columns=lamdba x: x[:3] + 'new' + x[-1], inplace=True) for d in df_list]`   Maybe... on phone can't test.

Comment: why you do not want to use  for loop

Comment: Thanks Scott, that was helpful. It was the kind of compact code I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
df.rename(columns={"A": "a", "B": "c"})
   a  c
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

This is taken right from the pandas [website](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this working on a project:

my answer:

```
for x in df_list:
    x.columns = ["colnew1", "colnew2", "colnew3"]
```

yes it's a loop, but it solves the issue of column names not being the same in the list of data frames, it's compact, and it's fast.