# Rename Columns in a Pandas Dataframe with values form dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame read from an excel file. **Note**: the column names remain the same but the position of the column might vary in the excel file.

**df**

```
    colA    colB    colC   ...
0   val11   val12   val13  ... 
1   val21   val22   val23  ...
... ... ...
```

I have a list of dictionaries that should be used to change the column names, which is as below

**field_map**

```
    [{"file_field" : "colA" , "table_field" : "tab1"},
     {"file_field" : "colB" , "table_field" : "tab2"},
     {"file_field" : "colC" , "table_field" : "tab3"},
      ... ... ...]
```

I could convert the column keys for each row in the DataFrame separately in this way and using the `new_dt` for further operations.

```
file_dt = df.to_dict("records")

for each_entry in file_dt:
    new_dt = {}
    for field in field_map:      
        new_dt[field['table_field'] = each_entry[field['file_field']]
    ... ... ...
```

This method is taking too long when my file is large.

I want to change the column headers of the data Frame before processing the entries further, this will reduce a lot of processing time for me. Kindly help me with this. I'm expecting the data frame to be something like this

**Expected df**

```
    tab1    tab2    tab3   ...
0   val11   val12   val13  ... 
1   val21   val22   val23  ...
... ... ...
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try this, ```df.rename(columns={col['file_field'] : col['table_field'] for col in field_map}, inplace=True)```

Comment: Possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354850/4985099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) function in your existing dataframe `df`:

```py
df = df.rename(columns={"colA":"tab1", "colB":"tab2", "colB":"tab3"})
```

You would need to modify the `field_map` dictionary a bit:

```py
col_rename_dict = {el["file_field"]:el["table_field"] for el in field_map}
df = df.rename(columns=col_rename_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `field_map`  you can simply pass it to `df.rename` as:

```
field_map = {x['file_field']:x['table_field'] for x in field_map}
df = df.rename(columns=field_map)
```

Hope this helps!