# Changing multiple column names by column number in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am borrowing this example from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-rename-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/). I have a dataframe like this:

```
# Import pandas package 
import pandas as pd 
   
# Define a dictionary containing ICC rankings 
rankings = {'test': ['India', 'South Africa', 'England', 
                            'New Zealand', 'Australia'], 
              'odi': ['England', 'India', 'New Zealand', 
                            'South Africa', 'Pakistan'], 
               't20': ['Pakistan', 'India', 'Australia', 
                              'England', 'New Zealand']} 
   
# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame 
rankings_pd = pd.DataFrame(rankings) 
   
# Before renaming the columns 
print(rankings_pd)
          test           odi          t20
0         India       England     Pakistan
1  South Africa         India        India
2       England   New Zealand    Australia
3   New Zealand  South Africa      England
4     Australia      Pakistan  New Zealand
```

Now let's say I want to change the name of the 1st and 2nd columns. This is what I am trying:

```
rankings_pd[rankings_pd.columns[0:2]].columns =  ['tes_after_change', 'odi_after_change']
print(rankings_pd[rankings_pd.columns[0:2]].columns)
Index(['test', 'odi'], dtype='object')
```

But this seems to return exactly the same columns names and not changing them.

Comment: Pretty close to being a dupe... but ever so slightly different (-:  However, you learn a bit from these [Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46192213/2336654)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should/could not replace part of the `columns`. You need to replace them all at once:

```
rankings_pd.columns = ['tes_after_change', 'odi_after_change'] + rankings_pd.columns[2:].tolist()
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use `rename()` method and pass the `dictionary` of old values and new values as key-value pair in **columns** parameter:-

```
rankings_pd=rankings_pd.rename(columns={'test':'tes_after_change','odi':'odi_after_change'})
```

**Edit** by [`@sammywemmy`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7175713/sammywemmy):

You could extend the idea with an anonymous function :

```
rankings_pd.rename(columns= lambda df: f"{df}_after_change" if df in ("test", "odi") else df)
```

Comment: You could extend the idea with an anonymous function : ``rankings_pd.rename(columns= lambda df: f"{df}_after_change" if df in ("test", "odi") else df)``

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks for the suggestion....added this In answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `to_numpy()` and replace the slice:

```
rankings_pd.columns.to_numpy()[0:2] = ['tes_after_change', 'odi_after_change']
```

---

```
rankings_pd.columns
#Index(['tes_after_change', 'odi_after_change', 't20'], dtype='object')
```

Or using `np.r_` with `df.rename`

```
rankings_pd.rename(dict(zip(rankings_pd.columns[np.r_[0:2]],
                        ['tes_after_change', 'odi_after_change'])),axis=1)
```