# Unable to amend column name in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

New to using Python. I'm loading a csv file into a pandas dataframe - I then want to amend one of the column headers as shown below.

Loading csv file:

```
df = (pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, encoding='cp1252', low_memory=False,
dtype={'ID':'string',
'Address':'string',
'Postcode / Zipcode':'string')
```

Can't get this rename header code to work. When I print the df the column name remains unchanged.

```
df.rename(columns={"Postcode / Zipcode" : "Postal Code"})
```

There are 4 csv files that I will be loading using a loop and the name of the column will vary for each file.

Comment: Is that exactly how you're using rename? because rename is not inplace by default. `df = df.rename(columns={"Postcode / Zipcode" : "Postal Code"})` or `df.rename(columns={"Postcode / Zipcode" : "Postal Code"}, inplace=True)`.

Comment: @Henry Ecker yes that's exactly how it's coded sadly. Used your first option suggested and has worked. So thank you. Basic mistake from me. Thanks again.

Comment: As above.  And note when looking up the functions on pages like (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and the examples at the bottom they may show a change but not a permanent change (if the command ran twice the changes would disappear).  You either assign the change or, if available, you can use `inplace=True`.  Just to complicate things `inplace` may be deprecated in the future (but OK for now and lot's use it)

Comment: @HenryEcker happy to mark this as the answer if you add it as such.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming column names in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) is not an in-place operation by default.

The default arguments are:

```
DataFrame.replace(to_replace=None,
                  value=None, 
                  inplace=False,  # <- inplace is False by Default!
                  limit=None,
                  regex=False,
                  method='pad')
```

Either assign back to update the value in `df`:

```
df = df.rename(columns={"Postcode / Zipcode" : "Postal Code"})
```

Or set `inplace=True`:

```
df.rename(columns={"Postcode / Zipcode" : "Postal Code"}, inplace=True)
```