# Difference between renaming columns vs. replacing columns attribute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have got this 'change on copy' warning during a column rename with `df1.rename()`:

```
import pandas as pd    

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': (1,2,3),
                   'b': (4,5,6),
                   'c': (7,8,9)})

df1 = df[['a', 'b']]

#df1.columns = ('x', 'y') # Displays nothing
df1.rename(columns={df1.columns[0]: 'x', df1.columns[1]: 'y'}, inplace=True) # Displays the warning
```

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

However I don't get this warning when I completely change the column headers using `df1.columns = ()`

I don't get the rationale for the difference, I assumed both operations are equivalent, for example no difference is mentioned in [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas).

---

Note I'm not asking how to work on a copy of the original data, which indeed would suppress the warning. I'm asking about the difference between the two methods to rename series.

Comment: You are seeing the `SettingWithCopyWarning` because you pass the `inplace=True` to the `rename` method. The rationale for the `SettingWithCopyWarning` itself is given [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters) in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .copy() or .loc to make a copy:

```
df1=df[['a', 'b']].copy()
# or
df1=df.loc[:,[df.columns[0],df.columns[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.loc` to make a copy:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, ['a', 'b']]
df1.rename(columns={df1.columns[0]: 'x', df1.columns[1]: 'y'}, inplace=True)
```

To know more: [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=settingwithcopywarning#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Comment: Hi, does `loc` always guarantee a copy? `f = df.loc[1]; f.iat[-1] = 72; print(df)`

Comment: Don't extract a Series. `f = df.loc[[1]]; f.iat[0, 2] = 72; print(df)`