# How to rename columns in Pandas automatically?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with 240 columns. But they are named by number from 0 to 239.

How can I rename it to respectively 'column_1', 'column_2', ........, 'column_239', 'column_240' automatically?
[image]

Comment: more details at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'column_{x+1}')
```

Example output:

```
   column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4  column_5  column_6  column_7  column_8  column_9  column_10
0         0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8          9
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(10)])
```

Answer (score 3):

To do it with one column you can use

```
df.rename(columns = {0:'column_1'}, inplace = True)
```

Instead, for multiple columns

```
df.rename(columns = {x: "column_"+str(x+1) for x in range(0,240)}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: I believe this is the most elegant solution. Just for clarity I'd like to leave the most basic example of renaming one column manually `df.rename(columns = {'0':'column_1'}, inplace = True)`

Comment: It doesn't work...

Comment: @Alexander APS then  I think that the type of the columns is int, see edit, now it should work