# Rename column to specific value if it contains string (with .replace & regex)

Tags: python, pandas

**Solved**

I have the current dataframe df:

```
Farmer   Good Fruit
Matt     5
Tom      10
```

which I want to change to:

```
Farmer   Fruit
Matt     5
Tom      10
```

I am wondering if I can convert any column name containing Fruit, such as "Good Fruit" or "Dope Fruit", to simply "Fruit".

By using

```
df.columns.str.replace('.*Fruit*', 'Fruit', regex=True)
```

I was able to successfully change the column name to "Fruit". However, I'm not sure how to apply this change to the actual dataframe, df.

```
Index(['Farmer', 'Fruit'], dtype='object')
```

**edit**
Thanks to @wjandrea for the solution. The code needs to be changed to:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.*Fruit*', 'Fruit', regex=True)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(...)`?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Renaming column names in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

As shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16667215/2954547, you can rename columns using an arbitrary function, which is probably the most general solution:

```py
import re

df = df.rename(columns=lambda c: "Fruit" if "Fruit" in c else c)
```

You can also use the `inplace=True` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the rename() function.

```
df.rename(columns = {'Good Fruit':'Fruit'}, inplace = True)
```