# Rename all df columns by for loop

Tags: python

Want to rename all columns name with specific string.

Example:

```
print(Df.column)
A,B,C,D,E

and lag=2
```

```
    exog_pred.columns = [f'{col}_lag_{i+1}' for i in range(lag) for col in exog_pred]

or:

    exog_pred.columns = [col + "_lag_"+lag for col in exog_pred.columns]
```

Expected Output:

```
A_lag_2, B_lag_2, C_lag_2, D_lag_2, E_lag_2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming column names in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas)

Comment: Yes, issue resolved.

`exog_pred.columns = [str(col) + f"_lag_{lag}" for col in exog_pred.columns] `