How to change column name marked '0' (zero)?
I created a dataframe using the command
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

where data is a list of string names.  This worked, but the first column containing the string names is "titled" 0, and the rename command doesn't work on that column.  I was able to add other columns with desired names using:
for x in list:
    df[x] = 0

where x are the entries in the list.
How can I change the name / title of the column appearing to be named 0 ?
I tried variations of df.rename(columns={...}), without success.

Please, post a [mre]. And be accurate on what you've tried (not just "variations of df.rename". If we can't reproduce your problem, we can't help: so far we know "variations of rename" is a valid way to rename a column, even if its name is "0".

This should show you different versions on how to rename your columns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas?rq=2

As others mentioned , when you create a DataFrame from a list, the default index is assigned as a column.
You can avoid it by below options :
1.Set the Index:
If you want the list elements as a regular column, you can set the index to a specific name or remove it entirely:
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name'])  # Set the first column name to 'Name'

On a sample dataset it looks like below :
import pandas as pd

data = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name'])

print(df)

Outputs as
     Name
0    Alice
1      Bob
2  Charlie

OR
2.df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index.name = 'Name'  # Set the index name to 'Name'

